# Catch-22 with .gitattributes settings and initial clone of repo

Tags: git, line-endings, git-config, gitattributes

Due to some issues with a 3rd party library I am using, I have a requirement to never auto-convert line-endings for my Git repository.  It is a requirement that any code I push or pull has the same line endings stored in my workspace and on the remote (i.e. Both `<CR><LF>` and `<LF>` should remain unchanged at all times).

The following Git configuration allows this:

```
core.autocrlf false
```

To reduce environmental dependencies between developers, I have decided to use a `.gitattributes` file to configure this as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461324/22489)

```
* text=false
```

The problem I am having is in the initial clone of the repo on a new machine.  Because the line ending configuration option is now in the repo itself, the initial clone uses the local environment's global line ending configuration.  So, if a particular user's global configuration is like so:

```
core.autocrlf true
```

This means that a file with Unix-style line endings like this:

```
This file has<LF>
Unix style line endings.<LF>
```

Will end up in the workspace like so:

```
This file has<CR><LF>
Unix style line endings.<CR><LF>
```

It seems like a catch-22 situation, as it cannot apply the `.gitattributes` setting until it's cloned the repo.  And at that stage its too late.

The obvious solution is to ensure that all users have the following global configuration value:

```
core.autocrlf false
```

But then, this defeats the purpose of using `.gitattributes` at all.

Is there a nice way around this?

Comment: Does it (end up with CRLF endings)? It's not supposed to: the `.gitattributes` from the commit being initially extracted is supposed to apply.

Comment: @torek - yes it does.  I just tested this with a few small repo by committing a single file with Unix-style line endings.  When I cloned this repo to a Windows machine with `core.autocrlf true` it ended up with Windows-style line endings.

Comment: Interesting. That suggests whatever version of Git you have has a bug; there's code all over the convert.c source to control this, with comments, that imply it *should* work the other way. That code is very twisty though.

Comment: @torek - I'm using "2.15.0.windows.1" version.  I was planning to upgrade to the newer version due to the recently announced security vulnerability, but hadn't done so yet.

Comment: It should be `* -text`, which actually unsets the attribute, rather than `* text=false`, which just sets it to the (meaningless) string "false".  Details in the [gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible mitigation would be to version in your repo a script, which should be run by the developer after cloning the repo (as mentioned in the `README` of the same repo)

That script would:

- execute a `git config --global core.autocrlf false`
- reset the index, triggering the eol normalization [as I detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45599180/6309).

You can couple that with a pre-receive hook on the server side (assuming you are pushing to a private repository hosting server) which would reject any push with the wrong eol.