# Docker on Windows: Service 'db' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ./myscript 1' returned a non-zero code: 127

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I know questions with such an error have already been asked several times, however I couldn't find a solution so I'm assuming that my case is different.

I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM alpine:latest as builder

RUN apk add --no-cache bash

COPY bin /main/bin
COPY conf /main/conf

RUN ./main/bin/my-script 1

FROM mysql:5.7

COPY --from=builder /main/dist/sql /sql

ADD generate-databases.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

and **this is working absolutely fine** both on Linux, and on macOS(using Docker Desktop).

The problem is that on Windows using Docker Desktop I get the following error:

> Service 'db' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ./main/bin/my-script 1' returned a non-zero code: 127

why does this happen only on Windows, while working fine in other platforms?

Comment: you may want to check docker's version on windows, and share the script with us.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was actually not strictly related with Docker but with the line-ending format of my bash scripts, which on Windows were `CRLF` by default while they should have been `LF`.

To solve the issue I [forced LF format in my .gitattributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976986/force-lf-eol-in-git-repo-and-working-copy).