# Changes from other people showing as changes not staged for commit following git pull

Tags: git

I am working on a shared branch of a Github repo, when I use git pull to get the latest changes from other developers they are showing up as changes not staged for commit.

This is occurring in files I haven't edited so my only guess is that it might be line ending related. I'm running a clean install of Windows 10 using Git for Windows from Powershell with default settings (core.autocrlf=true). It appears to be affecting all files that other developers have edited since the last time I ran git pull.

In some cases it's also flagging merge conflicts against lines of code I haven't edited but this is less common.

Answer (score 0):

Start the same clone then pull process, but with:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

That will avoid any automgical eol (end of line) transformation.

After that, check if [a .gitattributes directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42135910/6309) is more precise.

Comment: Thanks, the repo is large so I will test it once I'm back on an unmetered connection.