# NPM Package - LF or CRLF or auto line endings?

Tags: javascript, git, newline, eol, core.autocrlf

I'm the developer of [an NPM package](https://github.com/squirrellyjs/squirrelly), and am trying to normalize line endings. I'm on a Windows machine with VSCode, so most of my files are in CRLF format. However, minified and sourcemap files generated by my bundler, Rollup, are in LF format.

I personally prefer LF format, and would like to have my distributed builds in LF format, as well as the files in my personal editor. However, I don't want to mess other Windows users using different editors.

How should I configure `.gitattributes`, `.editorconfig`, my VSCode Settings, and my Git settings to best accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is better to specifiy in a `.gitattributes` ([as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34810209/6309)) a consistent eol policy for files with specific extensions: see this [`.gitattributes` for instance](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/discovery-nodejs/blob/d779f36a9146ba70a3e9b650d5d65a219b71bda0/.gitattributes), which uses LF.

VSCode has ["`auto`" as its default `file.eol`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_new-default-for-fileseol-auto), which should be enough: Git will do the conversion on checkout, and VSCode won't convert it.

Comment: But won't Git automatically convert to CRLF on my computer?

Comment: @BenGubler no, because you would have set `git config --global core.autocrlf false`

Comment: Thanks @VonC! Sorry for the long wait before marking your post as correct -- it ended up being a while before I could test it out :)