# What is the best git config set up when you are using Linux and Windows?

Tags: linux, git, windows-7

I am a bit confused with core.eol, core.autocrlf, core.safecrlf for git config.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

I am using Ubuntu and Widows.

I had ^M, and other issues before.

Could anyone suggest the best git config setups for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As detailled in [Git on Windows (msysgit) - Unix or DOS line termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249932/git-1-6-4-beta-on-windows-msysgit-unix-or-dos-line-termination/1250133#1250133), I would use:

```
git config --system core.autocrlf false
```

That would avoid any automatic eol transformation (See "[Git on Windows: What do the crlf settings mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181870/git-on-windows-what-do-the-crlf-settings-mean/4182346#4182346)" for the exact meaning of this option value).

You can leave it to true, as explained in [git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf/1967986#1967986), but I prefer setting `core.eol` + some `gitattribute` files in order to fine tune some of the files I want eol changes on.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278) for more details.

Comment: +1 - I know there's a variety of advice about this, but I would also always go for `core.autocrlf` set to `false`, and make sure you only use tools that are good enough to deal with different line endings (a point VonC makes in the first linked answer)

Comment: But this setting give a ^M when you git diff, doesn't it?

Comment: @shin: for files written on Windows and a diff done on Windows, I never saw `^M` during a diff.