# status shows (new commits) in default directory, but not in repo

Tags: git, language-agnostic, git-commit

So I have a directory called `Codebase` as my default git directory. Within it I have 2 folder for Java and Python.

The directory structure is like this:

```
Codebase (default git dir)
---- .git
---- .metadata
---- Java
-------- .metadata
-------- Proj1 (git init here)
-------- Proj2 (git init here)
---- Python
-------- Proj1 (git init here)
-------- Proj2 (git init here)
```

See the following pic to see the problem I'm facing:

[image: git status]

As you can see, `git status` in `Codebase` shows that I have new commits and changes (in other files), but `git status` within the project directory shows no changes. This is the same for all other files too. I have no actual changes yet the files appear here.

What's going on?

Comment: Could it be a problem with line endings?  I have had "git add ." fail with no messages. As I recall, it was a line endings issue.

Comment: How a line ending issue? How do I find and fix it?

Comment: @KaranGoel like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17628353/6309

Comment: I ran the command, but the same thing still.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that kind of status when:

- `Python\Project` is actually a root folder of a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)
- That submodule has been updated to a newer SHA1 than the one recorder by the [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309).

Check if you have a `Codebase/.gitmodules` file, and a `Codebase/.git/modules/xxx`, which would confirm the submodule presence.

Comment: No `Codebase/.gitmodules` file aor a `Codebase/.git/modules/xxx`.