# Changing branches in git mistakenly results in modified files

Tags: windows, git, github, line-endings, gitattributes

I am using git (1.8.3) on Windows. If I clone a repo from github then immediately checkout a different existing branch on that repo, git detects modified files. *Usually*. Sometimes it doesn't. And the diff on all of the modified files comes back identical (including line endings). This problem has been observed on 2 different repos on at least 4 different PCs among my team.

And it's not always the same files, but it's almost always one of a few subsets of files in the rep. For example, sometimes it's the same 5 files in the root of the repo, sometimes it's the same 93 files in one particular folder, sometimes it's the same 16 files in a different folder.

Once git has marked the files as modified, if I revert or stash them, they are immediately marked as modified again, which makes it impossible to switch back and forth between branches.

I have the feeling it's related to line endings, but I've already added the recommended .gitattributes file and [renormalized](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings#re-normalizing-a-repository) each branch, but I still have these sporadic problems. Another possibility I've thought of is merging between branches somehow messed up the renormalization I did, but I don't know how to test that theory.

We all have `core.autocrlf=true` as we are all on Windows. Here is our .gitattributes

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text=auto

# Custom for Visual Studio
*.cs      diff=csharp
*.sln     merge=union
*.csproj  merge=union
*.sqlproj merge=union
*.html    text diff=html
*.css     text
*.js      text
*.ejs     text
*.sql     text

# Standard to msysgit
*.doc     diff=astextplain
*.DOC     diff=astextplain
*.docx    diff=astextplain
*.DOCX    diff=astextplain
*.pdf     diff=astextplain
*.PDF     diff=astextplain
```

Comment: is it possible to provide a reproducible example of the problem?

Answer (score 4):

There are two situations where I've seen this sort of thing happen:

- Line endings and all the crazy options Git has for trying to deal with those across platforms. (I don't use these features at all myself, and I prefer to store and work with files all with consistent LF line endings, including on Windows.)
- Repositories that have two or more files whose names different only in case. For example, `readme.txt` and `ReadMe.txt`. Git on Windows has great difficulty dealing with these situations, because there is only one underlying file that can be accessed through two different names.

Comment: Regarding the case sensitivity : maybe `git ls-files` will help you see what git has in store (I don't have a windows machine to test it on, though ...)

Answer (score 2):

[Never set `core.autocrlf` to `true`, always to `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628353/6309).

It is that simple: it is a global setting with unintended consequences.

If you have certain type of documents you want to manage in term of eol, do so only through [`.gitattributes` files](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) and [`core.eol` directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209806/6309).

That means: get rid first of all directory changing automatically eol (like your `* text=auto`), push that modification back to the upstream repo, and see if the issue persists.

Then, and only then, re-introduce those directives, not for every files (not for '`*`'), but only for files you absolutely want eol normalized.
And check if that works.