# Line endings in git

Tags: git

I am new to git, i was using svn earlier and we had issues caused by line-endings (CRLF and LF). now i am afraid this ll happen again in git too, the reason for my worry is different developers using different OS. and i am using a windows system with a Linux VM as my development environment. so project code is on linux and i edit it on windows. in the vm i have git which i use to push and pull etc. should i enable autocrlf to true? will it prevent issues for me? but i saw some ware i should set autocrlf = true in windows only. 
i hope someone can offer useful advice :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to "[Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings#platform-windows)", I would recommend to [*always* set `core.autocrlf` to `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628353/6309) (on Windows or any other platform):

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

You don't want git to automatically changes files on a repository-wide basis without your explicit instruction.

Once you have identified specific files which requires  eol management, list them in a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), with [core.eol directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209806/6309).

Comment: @Jayasankar, and consider studying [this `.gitattributes` file](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/.gitattributes) to get further ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Git.

Here is one doc can help you set up your git conf file to handle this. Read it and practise you will love git.

[Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)