# Git crlf index error

Tags: git

Sometimes when I scan for changed files from got GUI, it pops a crlf index warning and when I hit continue, it rescans the entire repository. Why do such warning occurs, and how it can be prevented?

Comment: i understand you mean git GUI? if yes which GUI client?

Answer (score 0):

It could be, for a warning like "`warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF.`" (espacially on Windows) because of a setting like `core.autocrlf`

Try `git config --global core.autocrlf` to see if the issue persists, as I described in "[Windows git “warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF”, is that warning tail backward?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628353/6309)".