# Visual Studio 2013 issue with iTextSharp.5.5.5

Tags: visual-studio, itext

The file AGPL.txt for iTextSharp.5.5.5 is automatically changed just by opening a solution in visual studio 2013; git shows it as modified. how can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: When you diff before and after what do you see that's different? If I were to guess, VS is changing the line endings from Unix to Windows.

Comment: when I do git diff, I get this: "warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in /iTextSharp.5.5.5/AGPL.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory." When I do git gui, I get this: "No differeces detected.
AGPL.txt has no changes.
The modification date of this file was updated by another application,
but the content within the file was not chnaged.
A rescan will be automatically started to find other files which may have the same state."

Comment: You could try changing your [git settings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17628353/231316) for [line endings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9094476/231316). Otherwise I'd just commit it with the note for the line ending changing and move on.