# error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection timed out

Tags: git, gitlab

When I push a single or two files I can push successfully but when I try to push many files I am getting the message after a long time

```
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have applied the solution by increasing the postBuffer but still not working.

The response of the detailed push command

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push origin backend
```

is following

```
* Couldn't find host gitlab.odookorea.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host gitlab.odookorea.com: 0x918de0 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host gitlab.odookorea.com
* Connected to gitlab.odookorea.com (182.237.84.46) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'abbas'
> GET /hyuna/fruits-passion.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: gitlab.odookorea.com
Authorization: Basic YWJiYXM6QWJiYXMxMjM1IQ==
User-Agent: git/2.18.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Accept-Language: en-US, *;q=0.9
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Fri, 20 Jul 2018 04:06:36 GMT
< Content-Type: application/x-git-receive-pack-advertisement
< Content-Length: 603
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< 
* Connection #0 to host gitlab.odookorea.com left intact
Enumerating objects: 525, done.
Counting objects: 100% (525/525), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (322/322), done.
Writing objects: 100% (521/521), 221.37 KiB | 73.79 MiB/s, done.
Total 521 (delta 157), reused 492 (delta 147)
* Couldn't find host gitlab.odookorea.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host gitlab.odookorea.com: 0x918de0 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host gitlab.odookorea.com
* Connected to gitlab.odookorea.com (182.237.84.46) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'abbas'
> POST /hyuna/fruits-passion.git/git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: gitlab.odookorea.com
Authorization: Basic YWJiYXM6QWJiYXMxMjM1IQ==
User-Agent: git/2.18.0
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Content-Type: application/x-git-receive-pack-request
Accept: application/x-git-receive-pack-result
Content-Length: 226841

* Send failure: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I am trying to solve it from last week but unable to solve it. Please help me to solve it.

Thank You!

Comment: Can you tell us what you are pushing here?  In one of the commits, did you add several large (possibly binary) files?

Comment: First of all Thank you for your quick response. It has many PHP files and if I push from my colleague computer the same files I can push successfully. I am using the Ubuntu 16.04 and git version is 2.18.0

Comment: `Couldn't find host gitlab.odookorea.com in the .netrc file` ... I would start by looking into this, and then also check that the correct credentials are being used.

Comment: credentials are correct. If credentials are not correct then I can not push even a single file.

Comment: Could you push on an HTTPS URL, instead of an HTTP one?

Comment: I can't connect using https. It gives me the error 'Failed to connect to gitlab.odookorea.com port 443: Connection refused'. My colleagues can push using HTTP. There is one difference they are using Windows and I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: @VonC and Tim. When I add the files in git I am getting the warning 'warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF' And in my single commit there are many files which have such warnings. Do you think it is an issue?

Comment: @Abbas No (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628353/6309). Not for the push. Between you and your colleague, do you have different version of Git? Are you using a git config credential.helper? Does your colleague see the same output on a git push with verbose curl?

Comment: Git version was different before but now we have same git version. 2.8.2 . As far as I knows I am not using redential.helper. No my colleague does not see curl message.

Comment: I have found one more thing when I push the same files to the bitbucket repository it does not have any issue. Currently I can use only origin of http not https and ssh. It can be the issue in Ubuntu?

Comment: Hello @VonC , Today I install a new version of Ubuntu 18.04.01. I am still not able to push from here. One very strange thing I can also push from other OS such as Windows. Do you have any idea git http can not push in Ubunut?

Comment: @Abbas Do you still see the same error message? What version of Git is installed with your new Ubuntu?

Comment: Today I found one thing after change the internet connection it is working. But I am amazed how other colleagues can push without any issue. My ubuntu is 18.04 LTS. GIT is 2.17.1. It is making too much headache :(