# Git still shows “LF will be replaced by CRLF” warning when autocrlf is false and text is unspecified

Tags: windows, git

I have a repo that will only ever be used on Windows. And I would prefer that source control does not modify the contents of my files in any way.

I set `core.autocrlf` to false in global settings and verified that no local repo override was present. I found that there was an existing .gitattributes file in my repo with `* text=auto` as the only entry. So I deleted the .gitattributes file. From reading the documentation, my understanding is that this should result in `text` being unspecified, and will follow the behavior set for `core.autocrlf`.

However, I still get the following error when I stage my files:

```
LF will be replaced by CRLF in MyProject/src/static/images/logo.svg.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

If I understand correctly, there's something that still modifies my files. What is it and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as I mentioned in "[Windows git “warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF”, is that warning tail backward?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628353/6309)", make sure to:

- use a recent [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (more than 2.19 at the very least)
- set `git config --global core.autocrlf false` (you have done so, as specified in your question: good)
  Since you don't have a [`.gitattributes` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), there is no text attribute for [`svg` files](https://fileinfo.com/extension/svg):

  > If the `text` attribute is unspecified, Git uses the `core.autocrlf` configuration variable to determine if the file should be converted.

Second, check if an [`add --renormalize` would help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/6309)

```
git add --renormalize .
git commit -m "Introduce end-of-line final normalization if needed"
git push
```

Then check if a new clone of the repository would still ehibit the same message.

---

Note: the [warning message has changed with Git 2.37 (Q3 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72332319/6309).

Comment: Sometimes, svg can benefit from eol conversion (https://github.com/zellwk/zellwk.com/issues/17), but I usually avoid eol conversion as much as possible.

Comment: Updating Git to the latest 2.28 resolved my issue. Git had been installed on my machine by Visual Studio and I wrongly assumed that VS' update mechanism would keep Git up to date. I was still using version 2.17.2. From your referenced answer it looks like this was a bogus warning. I had not found your answer as my search terms returned other results that weren't helpful. Thanks a bunch!