# Blazor WASM on Github Pages: git modifies line endings even with .gitattributes set

Tags: git, blazor, github-pages, blazor-webassembly

To get around the issue of Git modifying the line endings of static Blazor files, most people are recommending that you create a .gitattributes file with "* binary" as its only contents to force git to treat these files as binary instead of text. In video tutorials that I have followed line by line, this works as intended.

When I do the same locally, I still get one file, dotnet.5.0.3.js, having its line endings modified, which in turn causes the sha256 integrity checks to fail.

Is there another method I can try instead? You can see the project's gh-pages branch here (https://github.com/TDuffinNTU/gh-blazor/tree/gh-pages) which is identical to the one I'm copying from a tutorial, which works just fine.

Comment: I've also just tried adding the path to the dotnet.5.0.3.js explicitly to the .gitattributes file to no avail.

Comment: It seems likely that something created the .js file and wrote it into Git and *then* set the `.gitattributes` file up, after it was a bit too late. If so, `git rm --cached` the file and then `git add` it again (that's the rude/crude way, `git add --renormalized` lets you skip the rm step but doesn't work in some rather old Git versions).

Comment: I figured there was some kind of order of operations issue, so I did a few builds where the gitattributes file was kept on the branch while everything else was deleted, committing inbetween. I'll try your other suggestions later :)

Comment: Okay so I think I've done it! I had to install git-scm on my work laptop to use it in the terminal, and noticed that there's an installer option that configures the auto crlf endings. I disabled it (which I know is bad practice usually but my line endings for everything else has already been altered for the build project anyway) so I think that's now working as intended!!

Answer (score 0):

So git-scm by default set auto CRLF to true (core.CRLF = true I think?) which must take precedence over my gitattributes file.

Having installed git-scm on a different machine and changing the default during the installation process it's now correctly preserving line endings and my deployment is working!

You can also edit your `.gitconfig` file from the commandline or locate it in your `C:/Users/$USER` folder and modify it there.

Thanks a bunch to Torek for their kind suggestions which prompted me to install on my work machine and lead me to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used this command and it work for me

```
 git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

from the very long answer here [Windows git "warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF", is that warning tail backward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628305/windows-git-warning-lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-is-that-warning-tail-backwar)