# Error while adding file to staging area using Git

Tags: git

[image]

Getting this error while using command - `git add .`
I have tried the solution - `git config core.autocrlf true`
But its not working. Anyone suggest a better solution.

Comment: First of all, why are you adding node-modules to git? You can install node-modules from package.json. So only that needs to be added.

Comment: Note that it's a warning, not an error.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors).

Comment: I will take care from next time, not to upload code in the form of an image. Thanks for the review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the warning message itself ("[Windows git "warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF", is that warning tail backward?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628353/6309)"), always use:

- `git config --global core.autocrlf false`
- a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) with [`core.eol` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209806/6309)

And in your case, as commented, add `node_modules` to your `.gitignore`, as it is usually done in [Node project `.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/ce5da10a3a43c4dd8bd9572eda17c0a37ee0eac1/Node.gitignore#L41-L43).