# why git add commad not works?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Iam trying to push files on githum but its give me such errors.

Warning: in the working copy of

```
.dart_tool/dartpad/web_plugin_registrant.dart', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of '.dart_tool/flutter_build/5858a742c42e73c8f0e5b45ebdff649f/kernel_snapshot.d', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of '.dart_tool/package_config.json', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of '.dart_tool/package_config_subset', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of '.gitattributes', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'analysis_options.yaml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/.gitignore', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/app/build.gradle', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/lgoin_ui/MainActivity.kt', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/app/src/main/res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/app/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/build.gradle', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/gradle.properties', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/lgoin_ui_android.iml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'android/settings.gradle', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'build/app/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/lgoin_ui/BuildConfig.java', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
```

Iam tryin to add my code on github

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)

Comment: bro i may suggest u Use GithubDesktop. no need to write any command

Comment: Hi, you should check the following StackOverflow Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628305/windows-git-warning-lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-is-that-warning-tail-backwar

Comment: This is not an error, it's just a warning that some special characters in your files will be replaced in git

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command `git config --global core.autocrlf false` recommend in this answer here [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628305/windows-git-warning-lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-is-that-warning-tail-backwar).