# What is the syntax in .git/config to use Linux line endings in a Windows repository?

Tags: windows, linux, git, configuration, eol

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git on Windows: What do the crlf settings mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181870/git-on-windows-what-do-the-crlf-settings-mean)

I am editing Linux files in on a Windows system with Unix EOL aware editors. How can a particular repository be set to respect Linux line endings, ie treat as though it is a Linux system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

After this it should not touch line endings.

Comment: my initial choice was to set core.autocrlf to input but after reading the question referred to Mat comment above I settled for core.autocrlf false