# How to undo the damage of autocrlf?

Tags: git, git-svn

I've been using git with autocrlf set to true for a while. I've been using it with git-svn through cygwin. It's been causing me a bunch of problems and I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016673/definitive-recommendation-for-git-autocrlf-settings) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249932/git-1-6-4-beta-on-windows-msysgit-unix-or-dos-line-termination) that I should probably turn it off. How can I "undo the damage" between trunk and master?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to fix it in a single commit and then leave it alone, you could do something like:

```
find . -not \( -path ./.git -prune \) -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/\r//g' {} +
```

Note: This will remove CRs from *every file in the repository*. Add `-name '*.someext'` or other clauses after `-type f` to adjust the find's extent.

If you want to edit prior commits (note that this will break other people trying to merge their changes into your branch!), you can use `git filter-branch` - write a script that does something similar to the `find` invocation above, then pass it in with something like

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter /full/path/to/myscript.sh master otherbranch
```

This will rewrite history, eliminating any CR that has ever been in the source code repository. Note that this will likely break git-svn if you run it across any commits created by git-svn. You can use something like `trunk..mylocalbranch` to only run it on local commits.