# How to repair CRLF in GIT repository to avoid merge conflicts

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

I created my repo with `autocrlf=true` and then made some checkouts and commits with `autocrlf=false`. Then switched back to `autocrlf=true` (OS Win).
Everything seemed to be OK, until I started some merges between branches. Many merge conflicts arose, where whole file was marked as changed due to changed `eols` (I suppose it were those files, which were checked out and commited with `autocrlf=false`).

There is some history, which is worth for me, so I prefer to make some conversion or fixing commits with converted `eols` rather to creating new repo and starting new life.

This is how I understand `autocrlf` (OS Win):

case if `autocrlf=true`

```
WorkingTree ->  commit  -> GITRepository
CRLF         CRLF to LF      LF
LF           no conv.        LF
WorkingTree <- checkout <- GITRepository
CRLF         LF to CRLF      LF
```

case if `autocrlf=false`

```
WorkingTree ->  commit  -> GITRepository
CRLF         no conv.      CRLF
LF           no conv.      LF
WorkingTree <- checkout <- GITRepository
CRLF         no conv.      CRLF
LF           no conv.      LF
```

Now I would like to use GIT with `autocrlf=false`, so I decided to checkout each branch, repair `eols` of source files with utility [EOL converter](http://www.totato.com/eolconverter/) and commit back with CRLF. I did it, but after time, there are still some files, which probably were not checked out after I changed setting of `autocrlf` to `false` (or these files came to merge from older not fixed commits? During conversion I used mask *.filetype to automate processing all LF to CRLF so there's no other explanation for such situation for me).
I also tried to `touch` the files, to re-commit them all (as I saw somewhere here in stackoverflow) but date change is not relevant for GIT AFAIK. I have also read [How to undo the damage of autocrlf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117678/how-to-undo-the-damage-of-autocrlf), but not sure it's my case, and also don't understand the wizard's tricks.

How can I get away from this mess, please?

Comment: have you tried `autocrlf=input`? if your repo was not made publicly available you can use that and `filter-branch --index-filter` to clean up line endings in your history

Comment: @knittl: If I understand, this will rewrite all commits in history with LF. Am I right? Then I will probably have to turn `autocrlf=true` to get `CRLF` after checkout (OS Win). Is there an option to convert repo directly to `CRLF` and leave `autocrlf=false` after that?

Comment: once the repository is converted to CRLF you should be able have `autocrlf=false` thus no line endings are converted and stay the way they are in the file

Comment: @knittl: So setting `autocrlf=input` causes _conversion during commit, no conversion during checkout_. What exactly happens on Windows machine? Repository will be all CRLF, or all LF? I cannot find this in manual. Thanks.

Comment: from the [git config manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html): »This variable can be set to `input`, in which case no output conversion is performed.«

Comment: @knittl: I understand, but what input conversion will be performed? Ok, I'll try on some test repo, thanks.

Comment: input conversion should be `CRLF→LF`

Comment: @knittl: Hi again, I tried to use this command, but it's not complete, what should follow after `filter-branch --index-filter` ? Thanks.

Comment: andik: try `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'true;' --all`. I think you will need tree-filter instead of index-filter because crlf conversion only happens on checkout (in other words: you need a worktree). `'true;'` is just a dummy filter here which actually does not do anything

Answer (score 2):

Use the git merge option "ignore-space-change" or "ignore-all-space" for the "recursive" strategy.  This option is in 1.7.4.1, at least.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868314/git-merge-xignore-space-change-by-default - excellent. Thank you @e40!

Answer (score -2):

Easy answer: Unless you ARE doing x-platform dev with non-Windows, set this to false. There is no need for your source control to bastardize your files for you. After fixing any remaining issues you should be flying. Make sure the others working with you also set this to false.

Comment: I suggest to have this option ALWAYS to true on windows - you gonna run into lots of trouble with other plattforms if you actually don't.

Comment: this is not an answer relevant to "repair"