# git merge -Xignore-space-change by default

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-config

How can I set the option `ignore-space-change` for all merges using `git config`?

I could perhaps use an alias on `merge`, but since I want that setting to apply to `git stash pop`, `git stash apply`, `git pull` and `git merge`, and others if any, I'd like a cleaner way than setting up many aliases (I don't even know if I could set up an alias `stash` for the subcommands).

I looked in the docs, but couldn't find the configuration option to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make git diff --ignore-space-change the default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310033/how-to-make-git-diff-ignore-space-change-the-default)

Comment: @ThomasRuiz it's definitely related, but that question is only about `git diff`, not `git merge` (Maybe `git merge` relies on `git diff` internally?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per-branch:

```
git config branch.$branchname.mergeoptions "-X ignore-space-change"
```

found by scanning [the git config docs](ftp://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for "merge".  If there's a global option setter I don't see it, a git alias would probably do it:

```
git config alias.i-s-c-merge "merge -X ignore-space-change"
```

and I think every shell has tab completion on git commands these days so it's `git i-` and tabkey instead of spacebar.

Comment: Which branch does that affect? If I set mergeoptions on `master`, and want to merge `new_feature` into it, do I need the setting on `master`, on `new_feature`, or on both?