# Github showing empty changes for new commits

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

My Github for windows is showing some files to have changes, but when I compare the files they are the same!

I have a screenshot here:

[image: Link to image]

I can actually edit these files and then the error goes away, but then it comes back with a new file at random...

Any ideas?

Comment: It's probably just the line endings in the files changing from unix to windows styled line endings

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/11601865/6309

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. I resolved executing from console the following command:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

Comment: This seems to be the cause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes

Comment: Not work. the changes list still there. "this file is empty" still display in detail view.

Comment: Did you updated to the latest github for windows release? This bug has been fixed long ago I think