# Stuck repo using stash after crlf normalization?

Tags: git, newline, git-stash

I have my local repo in a state that **forbid me to either commit, stash, checkout to another branch or even discard changes**. So I'm just stuck.

I will try to describe what steps brought me to this situation, as far as I remember.

*Please, take a seat.*

*A not so long time ago, in another computer far, far away...* an other dev normalized crlf in the project according to: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

In the while (you know, speed of light...) I made some changes locally, commited, and pulled.

When I pulled Git said:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    wp-config.php
```

`wp-config.php` was earlier removed from the index using `git update-index --assume-unchanged wp-config.php` since its a template config file adapted to each local environment.

The base "template" can change. Nothing surprising. Here what I planned:

1. reindex `wp-config.php`
2. `stash` my own config changes
3. `pull origin master`
4. `stash apply` my config back

Things went wrong at step 3. `git pull origin master` still raised the error above, as if the stash was ineffective.

`git status` said `wp-config.php` had changes not staged for commit. That surprised me a bit after a stash.

Since I stashed my changes I ran `git checkout -- wp-config.php`... but without any effect! File was still not staged for commit.

Since I was becoming mad, I created a new branch my-config, added and commited `wp-config.php` into it, then switched back to master, deleted `wp-config.php` (using `git rm`), and merged origin/master... with success!

So now that master was up to date and clean, I planned to restore my own config without the help of Git (editing the file manually).

Since I wanted to know what happened, I switched to my-config branch, and tried here a very simple manipulation:

```
git stash
git stash apply
```

And guess what? `stash apply` failed saying:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    wordpress/license.txt
    wordpress/readme.html
    ...
    (all the files that where modified by the crlf conversion)
```

And now I'm stuck on my branch (and plan to saw it, Francophones will understand ;)) since:

- `git stash apply`, `commit` and `checkout master` gives the error above
- `git stash` produces a stash entry but doesn't change the unstaged states
- and `git checkout -- <file>` neither removes the unstaged state

The only thing I can do now is to delete all these files (using the OS `rm`) to be able to go back to the master branch.

*True story.*

**I would love to understand what happened on the master branch, then on my-config branch, and what brought me in such situations (I suspect using stash on crlf converted file).**

Important notes:

- I run on linux
- `git core.autocrlf` is on `input`
- my `.gitattributes` is the same as the one in "dealing-with-line-endings" article
- I'm relatively new to Git (2nd day living with it)

When I did `stash` on my-config branch it outputed:

```
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in wordpress/license.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
... (one for each crlf converted file) ...
Saved working directory and index state WIP on my-config: dbf65ad my config -- should not be pushed
HEAD is now at dbf65ad my config -- should not be pushed
```

(`dbf65ad` is the only commit I did on my-config branch)

Answer (score 5):

After some research i guess the following happened. Your workmate changed the lineendings which caused the first pull-conflict.

That's why you stashed your work, pulled the stuff (now without problems) and started to apply the stash again.

With invoking `git stash apply` git starts a [recursive merge](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bd3e186d811a13d8687584856f345a767e3e4d67/git-stash.sh#L480) in of your stashed changes.

The error-message just tells you ran into a merge-conflict. According to the developer's [stash-documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-stash.txt) this may be resolved by a `git stash drop` after resolving the conflicts:

> "Applying the [stash] can fail with conflicts; in this case, it is not
>   removed from the stash list. You need to resolve the conflicts by hand
>   and call `git stash drop` manually afterwards."

**Conclusion:** If the configuration of the line-endings must be done in a existing project it seems to be best practise to do so by using a `.gitattributes` in your project-folder. Since it gets distributed with your line-ending-change-commit, it will avoid the headaches switching your current work to the new normalization-standard.

## Changing line endings within projects & .gitattributes

According to the developers documentation of [`.gitattributes`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bd3e186d811a13d8687584856f345a767e3e4d67/Documentation/gitattributes.txt) you can change the line-endings for all files (in the active branch) with the following steps:

```
$ echo "<<filepattern>> eol=lf" >>.gitattributes
$ rm .git/index     # Remove the index to force Git to
$ git reset         # re-scan the working directory
$ git status        # Show files that will be normalized
$ git add -u
$ git add .gitattributes
$ git commit -m "Introduce end-of-line normalization"
```

Replace `<<filepattern>>` with a pattern that matches your source files - in your case `*.py` for python-files (a good pattern-explanation is given in this [`.gitignore`-description](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)).

If you have more than one filepattern to add, you may add several line-ending-definitions to the `.gitattributes`.

> **Attention:** Since the second step requires to delete the [`.git/index`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084921/what-does-the-git-index-exactly-contain) (which is branch-specific) this must be done in every single branch you'd like to keep.

If you have many branches to process, you might consider writing a short script [iterating through your git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846380/how-to-iterate-through-all-git-branches-using-bash-script).

Comment: It looks like when I added `*.py eol=lf` to my .gitattributes, few files got stuck, git stash etc., didn't do anything, commenting it out did unstuck the repo but I am still not sure what was the reason.

Comment: @VaibhavMishra this is very interesting, could i ask you to try the modified receipe, i recently added to my answer? I would really like to know how to handle this kind of behaviour, since it happens often.

Comment: Hi, I followed your  instruction, however after going to different branch, all the line endings reappear, looks like I have to do it everywhere(In every branch) for it to work

Comment: @VaibhavMishra thanks - it seems that theese steps must be done in every single branch you'd like to keep. One key-step is deleting the [`.git/index`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084921/what-does-the-git-index-exactly-contain) which is different from branch to branch.

Comment: agreed, thanks - can you update the answer with the comment so that I can accept the answer.

Comment: @VaibhavMishra - you're welcome. I generalized my answer, any further suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Comment: @Pierre i modified my answer to show my investigations on stash apply, this may now answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to reset your local module is to use

```
git clean -f -x -d
```

This effectively removes all untracked changes to your local module and puts it back in a 'vanilla' state.

`-f` clean files.
`-x` clean files normally ignored by .gitignore.
`-d` clean directories.

Now run `git reset --hard origin/<BRANCH_NAME>`. This will reset your branch to the state of the remote.

`git status` at this point should tell you:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

If you have your actual changes stashed you should then be able to `git stash apply` to put them back correctly.

If `git stash show stash@{0}` shows more changes than you expected you can just apply the ones you want to see with `git checkout stash@{0} -- <filename>`.

Hope this helps

Comment: `git clean` would remove all untracked files. I think untracked files have nothing to do with my problem. Moreover I have some personal stuff untracked I would regret to delete... anyway, a `git reset --hard` worked. But it's not a valuable solution since if I had important local modifications, I would have lost them (I know I can retrieve them with git fsck, but definitely not clean).

Comment: This worked for me where other recipes failed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, regarding the GitHub help page, I would seriously recommend setting:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Let reserve eol modification to explicit declaration in [`.gitattributes` files](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) instead of a global magic rule: [keep `core.autocrlf` to false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2016763/6309).

Second, you can see if you observe the same eol modifications on `git stash` with [`git update-index --skip-worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/6309).

Comment: With `git config --global core.autocrlf false` i'm now able to see clearly the CRLF differences in `git status`, but a `git checkout wp-config.php` does not remove the *not staged* status. (strangely, a diff, even a binary diff does not show me the CRLF diff... files are reported equal). And `git update-index --skip-worktree` have no effect, even in conjunction with `core.autocrlf false`. It seems like the CRLF handling in Git is a bit esoteric, even with `core.autocrlf` set to `false`...