# Why am I getting unstagged changes from a git pull?

Tags: git

I had a clean working directory. I do a git pull. Tells me I have 2 unstaged changes. This is false because I was not working on these files. I try everything I can to get rid of them and reset --hard HEAD does not work. HEAD clearly points to the latest commit in the up to date central repo, the one that was pulled from.

I am somehow able to remove one of the files, but the other one is untouchable. I delete is (with and without git rm) and then bring it back with reset hard and it is "unstaged change yet again".

I try git checkout --  and again, it comes back as modified.

I also tried git stash save --keep-index ... no dice. Tried git clean -f too.

I just want to sync with the latest pull, I have no changes.

Comment: Are you by any chance running on Windows, and if yes, what is core.autocrlf set to in your git config?

Comment: Strangely, maybe related to my just-asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123998/git-stucked-repo-using-stash-after-crlf-normalization