# No local changes at all yet git status reports modified

Tags: git

I have a repo on Linux A pushing to GitHub and then that is pulled to another Linux B.

I have changed *.dat to text in .gitattributes. and pushed and pulled it to Linux B.

On Linux B git status reports all .dat files are modified.

On Linux B I do a git reset --hard HEAD

Linux B git status **still** reports all .dat files are modified

Now if I push a change from Linux A to GitHub, the Linux B pull reports
"error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge"
Files listed are all the .dat files.

git diff lists every line changed, yet its a Unix format file and the repo stores Unix format file.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would have thought that after a hard reset on Linux B that you should have synced repositories. Perhaps try a `git clean -fdx` and if that still does not help, re-normalise the Linux B repository (this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings#re-normalizing-a-repository) might help)

Comment: When I committed the changes to the repo it reported changing line endings from CRLF to LF. I surmise that as a binary file, CRLF was put in the repo. I then changed its storage type and so LF was expected in the repo, but as it was CRLF, modifications were reported. Can anybody confirm?

Comment: @miqid - I only just noticed your comment. The re-normalise would have addressed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Changing an attribute, and committing/pushing the `.gitattributes` file isn't enough.

You need to add, commit and push the files impacted by your modification, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18875915/6309).

If you don't have any work in progress:

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
git add .
git commit -m " *.dat are now text"
```