# Git says there are changes but there are none

Tags: git

First, I was unable to discard changes to a file, I'd use `git reset --hard`, no errors, but the changes remained. I tried several suggestions from other StackOverflow articles.

```
git rm .gitattributes
git add -A
git reset --hard
```

---

```
git rm --cached [fileName]
```

I even blew away my repo, and immediately upon cloning the repo fresh it had the same modified file. If I manually make changes to the file(remove what GIT things is different using an editor) , I can see it in the modified list twice now (as in, when I run `git status` I see the same file with the same path listed twice under unstaged files). Finally finding this one that actually reset the file and removed it from the modified list.

```
git ls-files -m | xargs -i git update-index --assume-unchanged "{}"
```

Now, I tried to switch branches and it says changes will be overwritten, I must commit or stash my changes, yet, when I run `git stash` it tells me there are no changes. I've tried several suggestions, including trying to [update line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18875915/2059099) and nothing is letting me checkout a branch. The branch does have a "/" in it, could that be causing issues?

> C:\git\azureWebApps\CRM-WebAPI (qa -> origin)λ git status
>   On branch qa
>   Your branch is up to date with 'origin/qa'.
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean
>
> C:\git\azureWebApps\CRM-WebAPI (qa -> origin)λ git diff
>
> C:\git\azureWebApps\CRM-WebAPI (qa -> origin)λ git checkout feature/PEN-146-CreateUpdatePerson
>   error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by > checkout:
>           CRM-RestAPI/web.config
>   Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
>   Aborting
>
> C:\git\azureWebApps\RM-WebAPI (qa -> origin)λ git stash
>   No local changes to save

Comment: Perhaps the changes are commited? Have a look at `git revert`

Comment: so, did `git diff` show the changes?

Comment: `--assume-unchanged` does not sound good, it just postponed the issue by ignoring file at disk, but did not resolve its cause

Comment: @max630 `git status` says "nothing to commit", `git diff` does not show anything. Yet, `git checkout [branch]` says my local changes will be overwritten.

Comment: I am dealing with same issue on Mac

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Note:** this turned out to be a file name case issue after all; see "edit" below.]

> ... immediately upon cloning the repo fresh it had the same modified file

This means one of two things is going on:

- the file *is* getting changed, or
- Git's idea of which file is which does not correspond to reality on your machine.

> If I manually make changes to the file, I can see it in the modified list twice now.

This makes less sense.  It would help if you included a cut-and-paste of what you mean.

[**Edit:** per comments, this was something like—I would use the actual text but I have to recreate it since I don't have the issue myself—the following:

```
(boilerplate snipped)
    modified:   CRM-RestAPI/Web.config
    modified:   CRM-RestAPI/web.config
```

While *Git* treats these as two separate files (as they will be on a file system that is case-sensitive), if your *OS* does case-*folding* (and Windows or MacOS do this by default), there will be only one file, named with either uppercase or lowercase W, rather than both, with both letters in both cases.  This is a specific example of a general issue I describe below, where Git stores file names as nearly-arbitrary byte strings, but not all OSes do so.]

## Background that you will need to locate and solve the problem

Since it's not clear what the problem actually is yet, it's impossible to solve it yet.  It might be line-ending issues, or it might be something else.  You'll need the following information.

#### Every file exists in three versions

In most cases—which always includes any fresh clone—each file that you can see exists in *three versions*.  All three *should* normally be the same, but they *can* be different (on purpose or not).

In any case, you have a *current commit*, whose hash ID you can find with:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

The hash ID of the current commit changes as you check out different commits or make new commits, but there's always *some* current commit (with an exception that doesn't occur here).

Each commit lists a bunch of files that should be checked out if you `git checkout` that particular commit.  You can see those files, if you want, using:

```
git ls-tree -r <commit-hash>
```

which shows you in gory detail every file that goes with that commit.

Every commit is read-only—the files stored in this commit, under this hash ID, are stored permanently<sup>1</sup> there, and they can never change.

The *second* copy of every file is kept in Git's *index*.  This is the thing you are manipulating with `git update-index --assume-unchanged`.  The index is a central data structure that Git uses for many things, but it's perhaps best described as *where you (and Git) build the next commit you will make.*  As such, the index normally starts out *exactly matching* the current commit.  Every file that is in the current commit is *also* in the index, in the same special, Git-only, compressed format that Git uses.  (Technically the index simply shares the commit's copy of the file.)  The important difference between the index copy and the commit copy is that the index copy *can* be overwritten, after which the index is no longer sharing the commit's version of the file.  The index copy is still in the special Git-only compressed format, but unlike the committed copy, you can overwrite the index copy.

The last copy of every file is the one you actually work with.  This file is in its normal everyday form on the computer, not in a special Git-only format.  Because it *is* in the normal form, it's subject to whatever limitations *your* system imposes, and that's where we get into the interesting parts.

---

<sup>1</sup>As permanent as the commit itself, anyway.  If you get Git to forget about the commit, the files themselves will go away unless some other commit(S) is/are sharing them.

---

#### HEAD, index, and work-tree

We can illustrate the three copies by labeling them a bit:

```
  HEAD        index     work-tree
---------   ---------   ---------
README.md   README.md   README.md
somefile    somefile    somefile
```

and so on.  Git copies the files between these various versions, except that the `HEAD` (committed) version is always read-only, so to "change" the committed version, Git builds a *new* commit from whatever is in the index *right now*.

The `git status` command tells you about these by comparing, first, the `HEAD` version of every file to the index version of every file.  If something is different here, `git status` prints the file's name and tells you that this is a change that is ready to be committed.  Then, it compares the index version of every file to the work-tree version of every file.  If something is different here, `git status` prints the file's name and tells you that this is a change that is not yet staged for commit.

The `git checkout` command copies files from a commit to the index and work-tree, or from the index to the work-tree.  (These should be separate commands—and were at one point.)  The `git reset` command copies files from the commit to the index, but not to the work-tree.  The `git add` command copies files from the work-tree to the index.  The `git commit` command makes a *new* commit from whatever is in the index, and then arranges things so that `HEAD` now refers to the new commit.

## The things of interest, or, What to look for

Now that you know what's in the various parts, here's where things can go wrong.

#### HEAD and the index need not use the computer native name format

The *names* of files stored in commits and in the index are just byte-strings in Git.  Git is generally "encoding agnositc", as the phrase goes, except that it uses slashes to separate directory names from sub-directories and files, and an ASCII NUL byte to terminate these byte-strings.  This allows Git to use UTF-8 to encode file names, since UTF-8 encoding never encodes any character other than the slash `/` (ASCII 0x2f) as byte code 0x2f.  If you're on a system that uses backslash instead of slash, either it also allows forward slash internally, or Git translates the slashes as necessary, so that this all works.

This also means that *Git*'s file names are case-sensitive: the file `README` is entirely different from the file `readme`, which is different from the two different files `Readme` and `ReadMe`.  The same holds for directory names.

Meanwhile, your own computer may have a case-*in*sensitive file system: there's only one file here, whose name is whichever is the first of those you chose.  If you have a file named `ReadMe` and you open `README`, you get `ReadMe`, not a new file named `README`.  (This is the case on Windows and MacOS by default.)

Similarly, if your computer *normalizes* names like `schön`, there are two different UTF-8 spellings for this name, and Git will treat them as two different file names, but your computer will both treat them as referring to one file.  (This is the case on MacOS; I am not sure about Windows.)

If this is the problem, it's rather pervasive and difficult to deal with.  Your best bet is to bring up a Unix or Linux system, which *doesn't* do case-folding and normalization, and work with the repository to eliminate the problematic file names.  You can then check out any of the commits that has been fixed, since those commits no longer provide names that trip up your OS.

#### Line-endings and other filters

Aside from file names, you have also seen that Git can fiddle with line endings.  Repositories made on a Linux or Unix-like system will generally use newline-only (LF-only) line endings, while files to be edited on a Windows system may require carriage-return-newline sequences (CR-LF or CRLF endings).  To enable cross-system work, Git offers the ability, but not the requirement, to do some sneaky line-ending changes.

The way this works in general is that Git refers to some files as *clean* and some as *smudged*.  What's stored in commits and in the index—i.e., in the compressed Git-only format—is always assumed to be *clean*.  Whenever Git copies a file from the index to the work-tree, it *smudges* the file, and whenever it copies that same file from the work-tree back into the index, it *cleans* the file.

If you enable CRLF line endings, the smudging process includes changing LF-only to CRLF, and the cleaning process includes changing CRLF to LF-only.<sup>2</sup>  This means that as long as all files in the repository are truly clean, they become properly smudged on your Windows system, and are re-cleaned when you `git add` them before you `git commit` the cleaned files.

But—this is the key point here—*all of this process is optional.*  The Linux users don't pay for any of it because they turn all of it off, and the Linux-side Git repository then stores whatever is in the work-tree into the index version, *even if the work-tree file has CRLF line endings.*  These can then be committed, so that the commits' contents include the CRLF endings.

If you extract such a file onto a Windows machine and have CRLF cleaning turned on, the index->work-tree conversion leaves the CRLFs alone.  But now all the work-tree files will have their CRLFs changed to LF-only, so they no longer match!  They're all instantly changed (but not yet ready to be committed).

This situation is also extra-tricky because Git attempts, through various means, to know when work-tree files are smudged or clean without running them through all the smudging and cleaning processes.  (It's kind of slow—*very* slow, in some cases—so this is usually important.)  But this means that the "changed-ness" of files is somewhat unpredictable and hard to diagnose.  The trick is to inspect the raw file content, which is easiest if you once again clone the repository on a Linux system, where there's no manipulation at all of line endings.  You can then use a line-ending-aware inspector to see what's in the file.

(You can do this on other systems using `git cat-file -p` to extract particular files without any smudging or other filters or text conversions, and examine the resulting byte-stream with a line-ending-aware inspector.  How to do the latter on Windows, I have no idea—I avoid Windows systems, as a rule.  MacOS has `cat -v` and `hexdump`.)

---

<sup>2</sup>We say "includes" rather than "consists of" here because you can write your own smudge and clean filters, which are applied *in addition to* the CRLF tweaking.

Comment: "Git's file names are case-insensitive" – I think you mean "case-sensitive" here :)

Comment: @torek Update post to move the part about seeing the file twice in the modified list to be listed when I couldn't reset the file. Once I was able to get the file to stop showing as modified in `git status` it didn't show back up. I also added a copy/paste of my command line of trying to checkout a different branch.

Comment: @Josh oops! fixed

Comment: @jrpharis Once you've set `--assume-unchanged` (which is a flag Git sets on the index entry), `git status` *skips* comparing the index copy of the file to anything else. However, the file is still different (from the work-tree version). You have to clear the flag (`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged`) to get back to having Git compare the index copy. Meanwhile `git checkout` continues to warn you that the work-tree copy is not saved anywhere—i.e., it doesn't look at the "assume" bit.

Comment: @torek Ah, thanks, I was thinking it would be something that was cleared when pulling or switching branches. I'm decent with git, but we've definitely gone off the deep end as far as my knowledge goes.

Comment: Don't know if this makes a difference or not, but I was able to get around this by checking out random commit several commits back, that was not at the head of a branch, just fine. Merged our development branch into my working branch, fixed the conflicts, and commit. Then upon checking out the development branch again (with nothing modified), that same file shows up as being modified and I'm back at square one again.

Comment: Hm: as a diagnostic tool, try `git cat-file -p HEAD:CRM-RestAPI/web.config > /tmp/raw` and then compare the contents of `/tmp/raw` to the contents of the work-tree file `CRM-RestAPI/web.config`. (This assumes a Unix-like system; you'll have to adjust it for whatever OS you have.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171084/discussion-between-jrpharis-and-torek).

Comment: Found the issue, Git saw two different files (web.config & Web.config), but my Windows system only saw one. I didn't catch that when I mentioned it displayed the file twice in unstaged files, that there were casing discrepencies. Thanks for all this deep background info.

Comment: @jrpharis Wish my case was that simple.  Pretty much same what you have seen and reported but no help.  Here is the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214095/git-checkout-errors-even-though-git-status-reports-that-working-tree-is-clean

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue -

Shell file had CRLF line ending in develop branch and LR line ending in feature branch

When I switched to develop branch from feature branch, I was getting this issue of file being modified.

Following steps worked for me -

````
git ls-files -m | xargs -i git update-index --assume-unchanged "{}"

git reset --hard "LATEST COMMIT ID"

git checkout to feature_branch```

This issue will continue to appear until I merge my branches and have shell script with one line ending LF
````