# git still finds changes even after git stash, seems related to .gitattribute

Tags: git

I want to switch a git branch, but it said I have 2 files changed, so I did a stash.

```
$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on XXX: XXX
```

So stash is successful. But again checkout branch failed, and it still complain the same 2 files changed.

```
$ git status
On branch XXX
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file1.txt
    modified:   file2.txt
```

I think Git has a bug here.

The 2 files are text files, originally committed with unix eol, but some user complained when they use samba and open the files with notepad on windows.

So I added a .gitattribute with this content:

```
*.txt   text eol=crlf
```

It looks ok, but after some period when I switch a branch, problem happens. And there is no way to recover, the only clean way is to remove it completely and clone from origin again.

I am using git 2.16.2, will this problem be fixed in a later version?

Comment: Maybe some tool auto-edits these files even after stash? Like auto-change line endings and auto-save in some IDEs

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bug reports should be send to the Git mailing list.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50335447/1256452 for how to analyze the issue. I suspect in your case it is end of line issues rather than overlapping file names, as it was there.