# git - Switching to a local develop, then back to feature branch resets the status of modified/added files

Tags: windows, git, macos

I added some changes in my feature branch, staged, committed and pushed it to origin using push -u git command.

Next day, I updated my local develop and feature branches to get latest code from remote using standard git fetch / git merge procedures.

At this point, I am seeing some interesting things:

I am on my feature branch, `git status` tells me all is clean, this is correct

I switch to develop branch, `git status` shows all is clean, this is correct

I switch back to my feature branch, `git status` reports all my changes that I already pushed to remote day before as follows:

1. **STAGED (GREEN)** - My changed are being removed (which marks some files as being ready to commit).  The existing files are marked as modified and my changes are removed from them.  The files I added are marked as deleted,
2. **NOT STAGED (PURPLE)** - The existing project files I modified as part of my push,
3. **UNTRACKED (RED)** - The new files I added to the project as part of my push above.

I dont understand why is this happening but it should not.

If I issue `git add .`, no message shows in git, I am just back to the terminal command.

If I issue now `git status`, it now shows that my feature branch is uptodate "nothing to commit, working tree is clean".

Switching back and forth from feature to develop and develop to feature branches like described above on my Mac reproduces same problem over and over.  Doing so on my Windows machine is not reproducing this issue at all.

**So, my conclusion is that something is wrong with my git environment on my Mac machine**.

But then, I also tried getting a brand new clone of my project on my Mac (which now contains my feature branch since I pushed it with all my changes using git push -u command), then tried switching back and forth on that clone between develop and my feature branch and the issue was NOT happening.  That made it even more confusing.

It looks like something is not being updated properly with my git on my Mac machine.  What could it be and how to investigate this?

We are crossplatform team working on both Mac and Windows.  My `core.autocrlf` is set to `input` on my Mac and to `true` on my Windows.  I dont know other team members settings for `core.autocrlf`.

Comment: Can you give more details of how exactly you switch to your branches? Are you doing `git checkout <branch>` on the command line or are you doing it through your IDE? In the latter case, do you know what command it issues?

Comment: Each time I am about to start new work, I do git fetch / git merge on my develop to update it.  Then I start new branch from it by git checkout -b feature-branch.  I work on feature branch, git add ., git commit -m "xx", git push -u origin feature-branch. ... In order to keep local branches updated with origin, I sync with origin daily using git checkout develop, git fetch/merge (or git pull) to update my local develop.  Then git checkout feature-branch, git merge develop to switch to my feature-branch and update it.  All this is done through terminal....

Comment: ... but I observed issue described above in my post on my Mac only on both my terminal and SourceTree.  I am not seeing this on Windows in neither git command-line tool nor SourceTree on Windows.  I use SourceTree only to view changes in files, everything else I do with git is from the terminal/command line

Comment: Your workflow seems sound to me, and this does seem like a bug or a configuration problem to me. Maybe look at your ~/.gitconfig and <repo>/.git/config to look for some unusual configuration, or maybe for a difference between your Windows and your Mac configuration. But I'm afraid I can't help, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure `git config core.autocrlf` is *always* set to false (on Windows or Mac).
Any EOL conversion you might need should be done in a [`.gitattributes` `eol` attribute](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_code_eol_code).

Then check your `git config -l` in your repo on the two platform: a [content filter driver](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_code_filter_code) could be an example of automatic modification on commit, which might not be declared on the other platform.

Comment: Note: I come from https://medium.com/@mypascal2000/thanks-again-man-c2b199db980f ;)

Comment: Thanks Von, I'll take a look once I get back to this issue