# How to discard changes in working directory when you cannot discard it?

Tags: git

In a local checkout of a git repository I have the following status:

```
$ git st
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   projects/TouchDetector/5.6.1/_static/doxygen/Doxygen.css

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

To discard the changes of `Doxygen.css` I use the command

```
$ git checkout -- projects/TouchDetector/5.6.1/_static/doxygen/doxygen.css
```

However, when checking the status I see again the same status:

```
$ git st
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   projects/TouchDetector/5.6.1/_static/doxygen/Doxygen.css

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So is there another, more reliable, way to discard the changes?

I also tried to do

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

and to remove that file, nothing helps.

I would like to fix this issue **without** the usual solution, i.e. remove and reclone the repository, as it is 3 GB in size.

Comment: There could be two files that have the same path and name except the letter cases and have different contents, and your system is not case-sensitive. When the two files are successively checked out, the second overwrites the first. You could check by `git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep -i projects/TouchDetector/5.6.1/_static/doxygen/Doxygen.css`.

Comment: What is the output of `git diff projects/TouchDetector/5.6.1/_static/doxygen/Doxygen.css` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git refuses to reset/discard files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536863/git-refuses-to-reset-discard-files)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior that you observe is typical for cases where end-of-line style is different between checked-in and checked-out files. It can also happen when clean and smudge filters are configured. The reason is that timestamps recorded in the index are stale.

Typically, `git diff` shows nothing in such a situation. Then the obvious fix is to just

```
git add projects/TouchDetector/5.6.1/_static/doxygen/Doxygen.css
```

which updates the timestamps in the index, so that `git status` no longer detects a modification. Do cross-check with `git diff --cached` that this command did not record any changes.