# Cygwin + msysgit - wrong line endings sent to commit message editor

Tags: git, cygwin, newline, msysgit, nano

I'm using cygwin on Windows 7, but I've decided to work with msysgit instead of default cygwin git, because msysgit is always more recent. Everything works pretty well, except commit message editing. I'm using nano (form cygwin) and my msysgit is apparently sending an CRLF line endings to it, therefore they are displayed incorrectly in cygwin window (as *^M*).

Have you got any idea how to fix this?

Do you think that combining mssygit and cygwin is good approach anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: I tend to just use the vim editor that's distributed with msysgit. It's probably the most common command line editor on OS X and Linux too.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you think that combining mssygit and cygwin is good approach anyway?

I tend to avoid it, since msysgit is now much more preformant and up-to-date than cygwin regarding git. See "[Git under windows: MSYS or Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784743/6309)".
You could consider [using nano for Windows](http://www.nano-editor.org/download.php).

Check at least for both git the value of git config core.autocrlf.

Make sure it is false in both environment. See "[Definitive recommendation for git autocrlf settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2016763/6309)".