# aclocal error: ' is already registered with AC_CONFIG_FILES; and/or $'\r': command not found

Tags: c, automake

I was building a C automake project. Running "aclocal" is showing the following error.

```
 $ aclocal
 ' is already registered with AC_CONFIG_FILES./usr/src/ports/autoconf2.5/autoconf2.5-2.69-3.noarch/src/autoconf-2.69/lib/autoconf/status.m4:288: AC_CONFIG_FILES is 
 expanded from...
 configure.ac:890: the top level
 autom4te-2.69: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
 aclocal-1.15: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
```

I am using Cygwin on windows 10.

The configure.ac has the following from the line 886 to the end.

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create output files
#
echo $SLIM_VERSION > VERSION
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile \
      src/Makefile \
      src/genconfig \
      src/verifier/Makefile \
      src/utility/Makefile \
      src/test/Makefile \
      lib/Makefile \
      ext/Makefile \
      test/Makefile \
      test/system_check/Makefile \
      third_party/Makefile \
      third_party/zdelta-2.1/Makefile \
      third_party/google-perftools-1.8.3/Makefile \
      third_party/google-perftools-1.8.3/src/google/tcmalloc.h \
      third_party/google-perftools-1.8.3/src/windows/google/tcmalloc.h \
      doc/Makefile \
      doc/slim.1)
```

As suggested, I used "dos2unix" on every "*.am" files and "configure.ac", but running "make" is showing the following error.

```
configure.ac:596: the top level
cd ../.. && /bin/sh ./config.status third_party/zdelta-2.1/Makefile depfiles
config.status: creating third_party/zdelta-2.1/Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
source='deflate.c' object='deflate.o' libtool=no \
DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/sh ../../depcomp \
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../src     -Wall -export-dynamic -O3  -fopenmp -c -o deflate.o deflate.c
../../depcomp:行2: $'\r': 未找到命令
../../depcomp:行5: $'\r': 未找到命令
../../depcomp:行10: $'\r': 未找到命令
../../depcomp:行15: $'\r': 未找到命令
../../depcomp:行20: $'\r': 未找到命令
../../depcomp:行25: $'\r': 未找到命令
../../depcomp:行27: $'\r': 未找到命令
../../depcomp:行64: 未预期的符号 `$'in\r'' 附近有语法错误
'./../depcomp:行64: `case "$depmode" in
make[2]: *** [Makefile:419：deflate.o] 错误 2
make[2]: 离开目录“/cygdrive/c/LaViT2_8_9/lmntal/slim-lightweight- 
hlground/third_party/zdelta-2.1”
make[1]: *** [Makefile:386：all-recursive] 错误 1
make[1]: 离开目录“/cygdrive/c/LaViT2_8_9/lmntal/slim-lightweight- 
hlground/third_party”
make: *** [Makefile:425：all-recursive] 错误 1
```

Here,

```
行2: $'\r': 未找到命令
```

means
    line 2: $'\r': cannot find the command

Could anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: You have something wrong on or near line 890 of configure.ac.  Please copy and paste lines 880 through 900, or so, of that file into the question.

Comment: If you have `grep`, the output of `grep AC_CONFIG_FILES configure.ac` would also be helpful.  If you don't have `grep`, please try to get us that information (i.e. all of the lines in `configure.ac` on which the string `AC_CONFIG_FILES` appears) some other way.

Comment: @zwol I added the part of the configure.ac file. could you take a look at it.

Comment: Blech. I need to see more context.  Can you provide a link to the source code of this program, which it sounds like you didn't write yourself?

Comment: @zwol the code is here: https://gitlab.com/alimjanyasin/slim-lightweight-hlground  Yes, I did not write all of that but I extended the project, however never had to touch the configure before.

Comment: Looks likely that the files have CRLF newlines -- ie. that they're DOS text files, not UNIX files. Did you maybe use a Windows version of git to do the checkout?

Comment: If you open the file up in vim, run `:set fileformat=unix` and save it, does that fix things?

Comment: I'm looking at it.  Meanwhile, here are some things for you to try: (1) If you are building from a tarball release, you should not need to run `aclocal` at all.  Skip to the point in the build instructions where you run `./configure` and go from there.  (2) If you are building from a VCS checkout, instead of running `aclocal` (and then `automake` and `autoconf` and `autoheader` and ...) yourself, run `autoreconf -iv`.

Comment: @zwol, ...unfortunately, which newlines git uses on checkout of text files is runtime-configurable, so looking at the repository doesn't provide a way to get a definitive answer re: what the OP has on disk.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was thinking of an entirely different set of potential problems than it seems you are.  Your hypothesis explains the mangled error message and mine doesn't, though.

Comment: @arslan see also [Dealing with EOL characters in Cygwin Git and Git for Windows accessing the same repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407408/dealing-with-eol-characters-in-cygwin-git-and-git-for-windows-accessing-the-same); the lowest-effort workaround may to be use cygwin's own git to check out working trees you're going to be building and compiling with Cygwin tools, rather than using Git for Windows.

Comment: `$'\r'` is a CR character -- so this is still a DOS-newline issue. Fix remains the same. (That said, while in this case the answer *wasn't* invalidated -- editing questions in a way that invalidates prior correct answers is frowned on here; this is what tends to be called a "chameleon question"; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's effectively certain that your issue is caused by DOS newlines.

The giveaway is this error:

> ' is already registered with AC_CONFIG_FILES./usr/src/ports/autoconf2.5/autoconf2.5-2.69-3.noarch/src/autoconf-2.69/lib/autoconf/status.m4:288: AC_CONFIG_FILES is

The line beginning with `' is already registered with` implies that the cursor was sent back to the beginning of the line partway through writing the line to the console -- the exact behavior of printing a string read from a DOS-format text file while it expecting it to be in UNIX format.

---

#### Configuring `git` to check out text files in UNIX format

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git config --global core.eol lf
```

Comment: Further evidence for this hypothesis: I don't see any duplicate AC_OUTPUT/AC_CONFIG_FILES entries in the full configure.ac, but the DOS newlines could also be preventing M4 from interpreting \-newline as intended, in which case the AC_OUTPUT construct shown in the question would be taken as containing many repetitions of a file named "\".

Comment: I am trying to install vim on cygwin, and try your suggestion. :)

Comment: If you don't already have vim, do you have `dos2unix`? It's also possible to use `tr` or other tools for the same purpose; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf-in-a-bash-script for a whole bunch of possible tools.

Comment: @arslan You may need to convert all of the files in the `m4` directory, and all of the `Makefile.am` files throughout the project, as well as `configure.ac` itself.  The command-line tool `dos2unix` may be easier to install than vim.

Comment: ...or use a Cygwin-native git to avoid having DOS newlines on your files in the first place.

Comment: used cygwin git to clone the project, and did not work. maybe dos2unix is the option I should try.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy dos2unix worked,  hope "./configure" and "make" work as well. :)

Comment: re: cygwin clone not fixing the issue -- try setting `core.autocrlf` to `false` and `core.eol` to `lf` in your git configuration (as with `git config --global`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how can I set "core.autocrlf" to "false" and "core.elf" to "If". I am not very familiar with these. I also updated the question regarding to using "dos2unix".

Comment: `git config --global core.autocrlf false; git config --global core.eol lf`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy by doing these git settings, it worked. Thank you so much :) you saved the day.