# Git Extensions - can not Revert local changes

Tags: git, git-extensions

After some Pull cmd I have got 3 files that were 'changed'. When I checked these files I saw the changes were just in **whitespace format**. OK, I press 'Revert changes' (R):

[image: git ext UI]

All blinked then... I see these exact 3 files! Again!
OK, I choose in the right window - 'ignore changes in whitespaces'. 'Changes' are gone from preview. Files stay 'changes'.

I tried to stage/revert or unstage/revert them. Tried to delete physically then bash: git checkout -- .
They are still in change list!

I tried:

- git stash save --keep-index
- git stash drop
- git checkout -- .

They are ALIVE!!

How on Earth I could ELIMINATE these 'changes' in files?

Comment: Would it be too much if I hunt all Git Extensions developer team members and annihilate them one by one...

Comment: Forgot to say: git clean -df - no effect, too

Comment: try command line git reset --hard , or the same in git extensions. 
FYI - threatening developers that provide you free software is not a way to create goodwill.

Comment: Yep, I was terrible wrong. But get reset --hard had no effect, too

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
git rm .gitattributes
git add -A
git reset --hard
```

Source: [Unstaged changes left after git --reset hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383094/unstaged-changes-left-after-git-reset-hard)