# Git Reset unstaged files

Tags: git

I did the following steps:

```
git clone my/repo && cd my/repo
git remote add other some/remote
git fetch --all --prune --tags
git checkout -b newbranch
git reset --hard other/newbranch
```

and now there's an unstaged file. There are no .gitattribute files in this repo in any branch or remote. (So it's not the same as [Unstaged changes left after git reset --hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383094/unstaged-changes-left-after-git-reset-hard))

#### Edit

If I do

```
git checkout -b newbranch other/newbranch
```

instead of the last two lines, I still have the unstaged file.

What could cause this?

Comment: The likely issue is that your local `newbranch` isn't synced up to `other/newbranch`.  Could you try instead `git checkout newbranch other/newbranch` (after nuking your existing local branch)?

Comment: @Makoto Edited the question to include that. I assumed you meant `git checkout -b`

Comment: No, I imagine that `-b` is just going to create a new, untracked branch which happens to share a name with your remote branch.  I actually *did* mean `git checkout`.