# Got changes not staged after reset to head

Tags: git

I use git every day, and suddenly today i face with this problem.

When i use reset command(like every day) :

```
git reset --hard origin/development
```

I got the status "a not staged" file shown in below figure

[image: git]

Comment: What say `git diff`? On windows is quite common to have CRLF or permissions issues.

Comment: git diff shows the content of the not staged file

Comment: I've hit the same issue recently but had no time to investigate it. Try `git stash && git stash drop` to get a clean working area. Waiting for a response with a reason though.

Comment: Have you seen [Unstaged changes left after git reset --hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383094/unstaged-changes-left-after-git-reset-hard)?

Comment: I used git stash && git stash drop also i saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383094/unstaged-changes-left-after-git-reset-hard 
my problem still remain

Comment: Also when i use "git add . " the file still in red color (i mean i got "no changes added to commit !! ")