# Recover the lost files from git? undo the command git reset --hard origin/master?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have mistakenly given git reset --hard origin/master. when i run 'git reflog' It shows my recent activities. What should be my next command to recover my lost files?

```
MacMini3s-Mac-mini:Avacabs macmini1$ git reflog

1f666a8 (HEAD -> master, feature/AddingSegmentViews) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
73ae554 (origin/master, origin/feature/cardView, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
1f666a8 (HEAD -> master, feature/AddingSegmentViews) HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
73ae554 (origin/master, origin/feature/cardView, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to origin/master
1f666a8 (HEAD -> master, feature/AddingSegmentViews) HEAD@{4}: merge feature/AddingSegmentViews: Fast-forward
91a8d90 (origin/feature/Trip, feature/Trip) HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from master to master
91a8d90 (origin/feature/Trip, feature/Trip) HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from feature/AddingSegmentViews to master
1f666a8 (HEAD -> master, feature/AddingSegmentViews) HEAD@{7}: commit: Trip class Segments added. Tripsheet segment page pending and Trip confirmed segment icon pending
91a8d90 (origin/feature/Trip, feature/Trip) HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from master to feature/AddingSegmentViews
91a8d90 (origin/feature/Trip, feature/Trip) HEAD@{9}: merge feature/Trip: Fast-forward
5eac266 (origin/feature/aravind, feature/aravind) HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from feature/Trip to master
91a8d90 (origin/feature/Trip, feature/Trip) HEAD@{11}: commit: Going to start Trip class
5eac266 (origin/feature/aravind, feature/aravind) HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from master to feature/Trip
5eac266 (origin/feature/aravind, feature/aravind) HEAD@{13}: merge feature/aravind: Fast-forward
f5095d7 HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from feature/aravind to master
5eac266 (origin/feature/aravind, feature/aravind) HEAD@{15}: commit: Arvinth came
f5095d7 HEAD@{16}: checkout: moving from master to feature/aravind
f5095d7 HEAD@{17}: clone: from https://example.visualstudio.com/Avacabs/Avacab/_git/Avacabs

MacMini3s-Mac-mini:Avacabs macmini1$
```

Comment: try git reset 'HEAD@{1}'

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Showing: 'Unstaged changes after reset:' followed by all files in my project including the lost files

Comment: Try git add . to fix this

Comment: I got my files. Thank you very much @JohnDoe.

Comment: No problem. Make sure to accept my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do

```
git reset 'HEAD@{1}
```

and if it displays "Unstaged changes after reset:"

do

```
git add .
```

or check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383094/unstaged-changes-left-after-git-reset-hard) answer