# git unstagged file after git reset

Tags: git, github

I am having an issue with git. it keeps telling me that I have unstagged file.

even after `git reset --hard` or `git add --all` it still shows the file as unstagged.

I am using android studio4.0

[image]

P.S. tried all the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383094/unstaged-changes-left-after-git-reset-hard) and none of them worked for me

Comment: Most likely it was committed with different cased letters in an OS/FS that distinguishes between different cased names. And windows does not. Check it out in linux and see how it should look and if it's even just one file with that very name (case insensitive).

Comment: different cased letters is a possibility. but all the team is using Windows OS. any idea how to fix this? renaming the file would do it?

Comment: First would be better to diagnose it properly: I'd check it out on linux for that.

Comment: Try to do it on winfows without git bash but with cmd...

Comment: @zerkms what exactly should I check on Linux?

Comment: @dan1st Tried to do it with cmd as admin ..same issue

Comment: @RemonShehatta the **exact** full path (all the directories + the file itself) name, plus if  any of directories in path or the file itself exist multiple times (with different cases).

Comment: Delete the file and restore it from git?

Comment: You could try to delete the content of the repository and execute `git reset --hard`

Answer (score 1):

This is a case sensitivity in the filename issue : as you can see once the incriminated file is named `OnTime_User_Presenter.kt`, once it is named `onTime_user_presenter.kt`.

This means that, somehow, one commit was created in your git repo where the two names coexisted.

You can confirm what git has stored as a list of file :

```
# you should see the two capitalizations in the command's output :
git ls-tree HEAD -- longdir/
```

You can search with `git log` when this happened :

```
git log --graph --oneline --name-status -- longdir/onTime_user_presenter.kt longdir/OnTime_User_Presenter.kt
```

---

One way to fix this :

1. check that the file you want to keep has the correct content,
2. fix the content of your branches (see command below),
3. make everyone pull the latest branches, rebase their work on top of the expected branches, and run the renaming command below

One way to make sure the correct naming ends up on both your disk and the index is :

```
git mv <bad_capitalization> foo
git mv foo <good_capitalization>
```

For step 2., on each branch you want to fix, run the above command, commit the content and push to your central repo.

If you are several to work with the repo, step 3. is important so that someone with a messed up filename does not push yet again the wrongly named file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible workaround for the case insensitivity issue (on windows).

The problem is that windows uses case insensitive directories by default but that can be changed per directory.

So, just **make the directory case sensitive**.

Obviously, you need to decide whether you want a case sensitive directory or not. Programs/scripts made specifically for Windows may not work any more because they could rely on a case sensitive file system. (See the comments)

If you use this solution, make sure that everything you use in this directory continues working.

Windows provides a utility program for file system operations named `fsutil`.

Open `cmd`, `cd` into the repository and execute the following:

```
fsutil file setCaseSensitiveInfo . enable
```

See [this site](https://www.howtogeek.com/354220/how-to-enable-case-sensitive-folders-on-windows-10/) for details.

If you want to restore the default (case insensitive) behaviour, you can just execute:

```
fsutil file setCaseSensitiveInfo . disable
```

Comment: A word of warning : this would make changes that could break *other* software.

Comment: e.g : if other programs expect that `mydoc.docx`, `MYDOC.DOCX` and `MyDoc.docx` will open or write to the same document, well, it wouldn't anymore.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to discard all unstaged files , try this :

```
git checkout -- .
```

Comment: This is not working for me. plus it was one of the answers in the link I posted