# Undo local changes in git-lfs

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a git-lfs repo with local changes and I want to discard them. I tried the following command without success:

`git checkout file`

`git checkout -- file`

`git lfs checkout file`

`git reset --hard`

What command should I use?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Viewing the modifications with gitk revealed that r/w attributes were changed for all files. Contents are identical.

```
-------------------- .gitattributes --------------------
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Also tried the suggestions mentioned here without success:
[Unstaged changes left after git reset --hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383094/unstaged-changes-left-after-git-reset-hard)

Comment: Try one of : `git checkout HEAD -- file` or `git reset file; git checkout file`

Comment: @LeGEC None of these worked...

Comment: ah, probably `git lfs checkout` rather than `git checkout` after `git reset`. What does `git status file` display about that file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You probably manually set `core.fileMode` to `true`.  Set it back to `false`.

#### Long

> Viewing the modifications with gitk revealed that r/w attributes were changed for all files. Contents are identical.
>
> ```
> -------------------- .gitattributes --------------------
> old mode 100644
> new mode 100755
> ```

The `git reset --hard` will have *attempted* to change the mode as well.  Apparently this attempt failed, perhaps without any errors being reported.

This behavior is commonly seen on DOS/Windows-style file systems, where +x and -x modes are simply not supported.  Some adapters report all files as mode `644` (rw-r--r--) and some adapters report all files as mode `755` (`rwx-r-xr-x`); it looks like you have the second kind.

Git *normally* detects and adjusts itself for these kinds of file systems: at the time the repository is created, Git does a few "create a file and change its mode" tests.  If the mode changes from +x to -x and/or vice versa are obeyed, Git believes that the OS and file system *do* support modes, and it therefore sets a configuration setting:

```
core.fileMode true
```

If these changes are *not* obeyed, Git believes that the OS and file system *do not* support modes, and it therefore sets the opposite setting:

```
core.fileMode false
```

Note that this setting, `core.filemode` (sometimes in mixed camelCase and sometimes all lowercase: Git is case-insensitive here, though not elsewhere), tells Git *how your system works*.  It does not *control* the system, it simply *reports the earlier observation*.

If you, manually, *change* this variable, you're telling Git that you have replaced your operating system and/or file system, and it now works the other way.  If you did in fact replace your OS and/or file system and it *does* work the other way, your new setting is correct.  But if not, you have now lied to Git.

Or, you might take your entire `.git` repository and working tree and move them to a new file system.  When you do that, depending on your particular OS and file systems, it's possible that the old `core.fileMode` setting is now inaccurate.  Git won't know this—Git will believe the old setting.  By moving the files, you have, in effect, lied to Git, though in this case you probably didn't have any reason to suspect something like that.

In both cases, the fix is to correct the lie: inform Git how the file system really works, by setting `core.fileMode` to `false` or `true` appropriately.  Once it's set correctly, Git will know whether to assume the attributes settings it sees are valid (`core.fileMode true`) and therefore you'll see this kind of change, or not (`core.fileMode false`) and therefore you *won't* see this kind of change.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and I did not change this git config... but it was indeed changed! While waiting for an answer, I recloned the LFS repo and kept the broken one... It had `filemode = true`! Changing it to false solved the issue!

Comment: Ubuntu's native file systems do respect the +x / -x bits; are you using an NT file system to communicate with Windows, or some kind of shared drive thingy? Be careful with sharing: Git doesn't like anyone else to touch its `.git` directory.

Comment: no shared FS, plain ext4... but it only happened with git LFS, and I've seen this problem on two ubuntu systems

Comment: Curious. Perhaps there's a bug in the LFS Git wrappers. (`git-lfs <op>` runs various Git commands for you, some of which are implemented directly in Go, and some of which call out to command-line Git. The ones in Go are *supposed* to behave the same as the call-outs to (C) Git, but there can be bugs here.)