Can not remove files from git due to line endings
I do have two files in my project where git tells me I do have changes in. When I click on the changes the diff says "contents are identical". Which makes sense because I've never actively touched those files.
One of the files is a "yml" file and the other one "gradlew.bat" Both files are CRLF. When I do run git add . it gives me this error
warning: in the working copy of 'file.yml', CRLF will be replaced by LF the next time Git touches it
What I tried:

I tried to revert the changes but it does not work, the files are still there.

What I also tried was git stash and git git stash pop afterwards. And also git stash apply. Both had no impact

I tried to delete the files manually and then pulling from the repository. Files occurred immediately in changes again.

I tried git reset --hard and git clean -f -d

I tried git rm --cached on the files and git rm --cached -r .

I tried git update-index --refresh

I tried git config --global core.autocrlf false

git add --renormalize gave me even more files more yaml, bat and one java file occurred

I committed the files and run git reset --soft HEAD~1

I went to origin/main and copied the contents from the files by hand. Had no impact

I committed the files and pushed them to the remote repository. The changes were gone for a second but after I pulled from main they occurred again. After that we also merged this to main, then my colleague pulled it and now has the same error with the same two files, we reverted the merge. (So obviously git touched it but it had no impact)

Other people from the team that pulled from the repo (not my faulty merge) do not have the problem.

I deleted the repository and cloned it again. Files occurred immediately in changes again.

I uninstalled intelliJ and Git from my pc. But it did not help.


In .gitattributes those two file types are set to
*.bat text eol=crlf
*.yml text eol=lf
what could be the issue ?

This worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335521/git-how-to-revert-2-files-that-are-stubbornly-stuck-at-changed-but-not-committ

What exactly does git status return?
In intelij, what line ending is shown in the upper lower corner?



Git status returns: On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)
modiefied: file.yml
modified: gradlew.bat

For both files it is CRLF

Can you give more info about your setup?
Which line endings should be there?

I've just started having problems today - I do a pull, then git immediately thinks I've changed the files (I haven't). Windows user pushes file, I pull on Linux, rep .gitattributes

text eol=lf

I noticed git (Amazon Linux 2, git version 2.40.1) updated Apr-24. Related? I hadn't changed any git config for months; all working up 'til today (which may be the first time a Windows user committed).

for me it turned out that something within my git history was broken. Therefor it worked to explicitly tell git, that there are no changes with this command: git ls-files -m | xargs -i git update-index --assume-unchanged "{}"  (this is from the link I did post above)
