# Cannot checkout modified files

Tags: git

All of the files in my repository show up as modified in the index. I have no idea how this came about and I have been trying to remove the modified files from the index but I am unable to do so.

I tried the following:

```
git checkout -- .
git reset --hard HEAD
```

I've even tried to checkout a file individually, but even so it still shows as modified when I do `git status` afterwards.

```
git checkout -- path/to/file.txt
```

Do you have any ideas as to what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible the files have their end of line changes automatically (check the result of `git config core.autocrlf`).
I always try to [keep that particular setting to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278).

You have other automatic changes that can be applied on checkout or reset, i.e. various content drivers declared in a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes.html) (like `core.eol`, [or `text`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11011701/6309)).

Regarding the permission being changes automatically, try

```
git config core.filemode false
```

More details in "[Removing files saying “old mode 100755 new mode 100644” from unstaged changes in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1257592/6309)"

Comment: This. HUGE PITA when switching between multiple OSes/environments.

Comment: @NickTomlin yes, which is why I try to set that `core.autocrlf` always to false.

Comment: Thanks, I changed `autocrlf` to false and tried to checkout the modified files but to no avail. I also have nothing set for `core.eol` or `text`. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @ChrisB the `checkout` won't be enough: a `git reset --hard HEAD` would be better.

Comment: @VonC I forgot to mention that I tried `git reset --hard HEAD` as well but my index still has all of the modified files in it :(

Comment: @ChrisB then this is caused by another setting. Can you share a bit of the `git status`, as well as a `git diff -- aFile`?

Comment: @VonC The git status is about 1k lines, what part of it would you like to see? As for the git diff: `old mode 100755 new mode 100644`

Comment: @ChrisB ok, answer edited (a `git reset --hard HEAD` is still needed)