# Unable to revert changes in Idea IDE

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have several files shown as changed. If i revert changes nothing happens. If I remove them from disk and then run `git checkout -- .` from console they shown as changed again.

How to tell Idea to forget about them?

Other actions (like pull, commit and push) works fine.

OS: Windows 7.

```
$ git config core.fileMode
false

$ git status
# On branch bugfix/XXXXX
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: what files? Are they .iml or .ipr?

Comment: No. Regular java files.

Comment: is git pull is working under idea?

Comment: Here i didnot get clear idea what you said, you want to revert back those changes ? or you donot want to see files status(changed/modified)?

Comment: Provide us more information about these files, are they part of your code or part of the files modified by your IDE?

Comment: What's your OS? Also, could you please tell what's the output of `git config core.autocrlf`? And what are the line endings in the problematic files? you may have guessed what I'm suspecting at this point ;)

Comment: What kind of changes appear?

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBattula Idea tells me that files are identical when I press Ctrl + D, `git status` does not show any changes at all

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski yes I get what you mean. But this is something different. Because `git status` does not show anything. And even if I delete thous files and restore them with `git checkout -- .` nothing changes.

Comment: @talex I think by mistake files are duplicated , so find out those file name and check files in project folder.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBattula no, No duplicates in this folder. File name is unique across project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not complete solution. But as long my problem some kind of Idea magic solution magical too.

When I checked out another branch changes disappear. If I checked out initial branch it occur again.

Magic to all :)

Answer (score 8):

I guess the problem is with file modes! I faced the same thing some time back when I moved my development to Windows.

Try running `git config core.fileMode false` and then check!

Hope it help!

Comment: No. Problem in something else

Answer (score 3):

- By using `git status` we can find out each file status (modified, not modified).
- In our project, temporary files frequently change.  In this case, git repository says our files are untracked or modified. For this we have to add these files to `.gitignore`  to ignore them.

  We have to execute some commands. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762) and check the following commands.

  ```
  git reset HEAD filenamewithpath -> unstaging a staged file
  git checkout -- filenamewithpath -> unmodifying a modified file
  ```
- You can find the relevant technology's `.gitignore` files in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore).
- To ignore the files which we mentioned in the `.gitignore` file, we have to execute the following commands.

  ```
  git rm -r --cached .
  git add .
  git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
  ```

Comment: did you add .gitignore file to your project? and after using git status did you find any untracked files?

Comment: Yes, there id `.gitignore` file in project. And `git status` doesn't show any changes.

Comment: Hmm then, may be the problem is because of  idea IDE, please check the version whether it is latest or not.

Comment: Problem not in `.gitignore` file. Files is part of project and already commited into repository.

Comment: `git status` command will show untracked and modified files, but in your case it is not showing. I think the files which are changed are not in **git repository** please check once.

Comment: Files in repository. I tryed delet them locally and restore from repo. It doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to switch off Editor/Auto-import/Optimize import?

Second idea: the now famous LF/CRLF problem
http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/handling-lf-and-crlf-line-endings.html
[git status shows modifications even with autocrlf=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005688/git-status-shows-modifications-even-with-autocrlf-false)

I would tend to think about the second possibility.

Good luck!

Comment: Idea doesn't show aby changes on `Ctrl + D`, `git status` too. So it's not line ending problem

Answer (score 1):

There is a "Refresh File Status" under the VCS menu. Can't hurt to give it a shot.

Comment: Tryed it. Doesn't help.