# .gitignore and web.release.config

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitignore, web.config-transform

I'm trying to remove my web.release.config from my GIT repository, so I removed it from git with `git rm` and then added it to my .gitignore file.

But as soon as I copy again the file into the project, it gets added by Visual Studio to the pending changes.

This is the line in the gitignore file:

```
Web.Release.config
```

But it gets added:

[image]

[image]

How can I successfully remove web.release.config from git?

Comment: You have no trailing characters there?

Comment: Not one, checked multiple times

Answer (score 8):

- After adding files to the **.gitignore** file, to ignore those files we have to execute some commands.
- To ignore the files which we mentioned in the **.gitignore** file, we have to execute the following commands.

  `git rm -r --cached .
  git add .
  git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"`
- Please refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository) once.

Comment: The file is already removed from the repository, also git doesn't show it in 'git status'. It is visual studio that is trying to add it.

Comment: please check whether this file 'Web.Release.config' exists in your project folder. and add entire path of your file in '.gitignore' file.

Comment: Yes it exists, as you can see in the pictures above. I've also tried with the full path of the file, no success

Comment: after adding that file path in .gitignore execute above three commands once.

Comment: Yes, I've already done that, the file is not in the repository

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908453/unable-to-revert-changes-in-idea-ide it may help you

Answer (score 2):

This might not be a "proper" answer, but I think it's Visual Studio messing around. I've been experiencing the same problem with Visual Studio 2013 when I tried to exclude NuGet packages from the repository. `git status` shows nothing, while VS still shouting that there're hundreds of files pending to be added. I ended up just use a Git Client (Git Extension, which is bundled with the git installation package) and ignore that Team Explorer tab in VS completely.

Comment: Yes, it definitely seems to be a problem with VS

Answer (score 0):

Open your `.gitignore` file in a real text editor and verify that the encoding is **UTF-8**. Other encoding (eg: UTF-16LE) may cause this problem.

Comment: It was in another encoding, but I've already changed it and no effect