# Git Thinks I Have Unpushed Changes

Tags: git, github

I have noticed several times in the last few months, that sometime after pushing changes to my remote repo (GitHub, though I don't think it matters) my local git will believe the changes it has have not been pushed. In all cases, these are changes that *do* in face exist on the remote. Most-recently was this morning. I did `git pull origin master` on my machine at work to fetch three commits that were made from home. Then, when I did `git status` it showed the *same* three changes as local changes that have not been pushed to the remote.

Usually, I just delete the local repository and re-clone it from GH, but to be honest I'm getting tired of doing that. Between 4 machines sharing this code, it's starting to get silly how often I have to do this.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? Is there a better solution than to just blow away and re-clone? This has happened on Mac OS and Linux systems both, so I don't think it is specific to any OS.

Comment: Perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016404/git-status-shows-modifications-git-checkout-file-doesnt-remove-them

Answer (score 3):

Running `git pull origin master` doesn't update the remote-tracking branch `origin/master`. This will cause git to think you have local unpushed changes. Assuming `origin/master` is your default pull branch you can just say `git pull` or `git pull origin` and it will update that branch. Or you could use `git fetch origin` followed by `git merge origin/master`.

Comment: Interesting. I've always used `git pull origin master`, but this only happens occasionally, not consistently? Either way, doing `git pull origin` (without `master`) seems to have cleaned it up.

Comment: @rjray: Maybe you (or some script/app you use) also routinely does a `git fetch` or `git remote update`? If your remote-tracking branch is already up-to-date, then `git pull origin master` will not cause the appearance of local unpushed commits.

Comment: @rjray: the remote-tracking branch `origin/master` will also be updated when you push your `master` to `master` in `origin`, which may be why `origin/master` is sometimes up-to-date for you.