# Changes view in IntelliJ continues to list files where the only difference are LF vs CRLF

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have 2 files that won't go away in the Changes view.  If I look at the diff, it just tells me the committed version has LF line endings and the local version has CRLF line endings.  I'm working on a Mac and I understand linux based systems use LF line endings and Windows use CRLF.  Is there someway I can just convert these 2 files so all the line endings are LF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```

did the trick in my case, see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/handling-lf-and-crlf-line-endings.html

Answer (score 8):

I had the issue on Windows because I checked out the project using a Cygwin git.exe and IntelliJ used a git.exe from msysGit. Changing the git.exe under `Settings -> Version Control -> Git -> Path to Git executable` fixed the problem.

Comment: I also had this issue and this helped but I did have to revert all improper line endings so that the diff showed no more differences.

Answer (score 6):

In your case, you could:

- [convert those files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5852277/6309)
- set `core.autocrlf` to `input`:

  ```
  git config core.autocrlf input
  ```
- [reset it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18792689/6309) (make sure you don't have any work in progress)

  ```
  git rm --cached -r .
  git reset --hard
  ```

See more at "[git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/6309)".

Answer (score 5):

Simple and quick solution to is - **Shelve** & **Unshelve** the changes.
Works for me every time.

Shelving:

[image]

Unshelve:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on windows when repository was cloned using Cygwin (even with `git config core.autocrlf true`).

After re-cloning the repository with GitBash (configured as `git config core.autocrlf true`), the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, this following list finally works on windows:

- IntelliJ settings->version control->git path to git executable should use the git.exe in c:\cygwin\bin
- IntelliJ settings->version control->git ssh executable 'native'.
- edit environment variables to your account on windows add to path: c:\cygwin\bin and c:\cygwin
- get rid of the .idea in the project directory if it's already there. (very important !)
- restart intellij, open the project directory again.

So now the local changes won't show the 'identical content' files, and the 'pull' and 'push' are all working from IntelliJ. And I don't have to go to cygwin to do the chore anymore.

If the project is being worked on both Linux and Windows, make sure the following setting is followed:
Make sure you have this setting (git config -l) in the cygwin window:
core.autocrlf=input

on linux in order for things to work properly you also have to have this setting as well:
core.autocrlf=input

this is how to set it:
git config --global core.autocrlf input

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue when you `git clone` the repository via Cygwin git executable and IntelliJ uses the git exectuable at `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`.

I solved this by cloning the project again via intellij (`ctrl-shift-a` : "check out from version control" -> `Git`).

Now everything seems to be in order and I can't see any changes until `Version Control`.