# Bundler keeps removing 'BUNDLED WITH' section of Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

My machine is running bundler 1.10.6. When I run bundle install, the BUNDLED WITH block is removed from my Gemfile.lock.

```
BUNDLED WITH
    1.10.5
```

If I run `git checkout -- Gemfile.lock`, it doesn't revert the change. This is a problem because it means I can't get a clear working HEAD so I can't rebase, cherry-pick or run other important git commands.

I understand why bundler usually updates this section of the Gemfile.lock to log the bundler version, but why would it be removing the section?

You can [read more about the BUNDLED WITH section at the bundler blog](http://bundler.io/blog/2015/06/24/version-1-10-released.html#bundled-with).

Comment: So, you said you have `1.10.6` in your machine but your `BUNDLED_WITH` is showing `1.10.5`!

Comment: can you try: `bundler -v` and `bundle exec bundler -v` and show me the output?

Comment: Recently I faced similar problem with Gemfile.lock. The problem may be with line ending. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016404/git-status-shows-modifications-git-checkout-file-doesnt-remove-them) helped me. Try `git rm Gemfile.lock && git checkout -- Gemfile.lock` if you need to do something urgent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do to is to upgrade the "bundler" gem (something that is also recommended)-
Simply run: `gem update bundler`
This would work for most people.

Also, try: `gem update rubygems-bundler` in case that comes from a rubygems issue (which was resolved)

Comment: hmm, that's what I thought, but in practice I'm finding different. With bundler 1.11.2, a Gemfile.lock that says BUNDLED WITH 1.11.2, same ruby and rvm 1.26.11, and the repo deployed on two identical centos servers  .. `bundle install` removes the BUNDLED WITH on one machine, but leaves it in place on the other. go figure!

Comment: it seems my issue was caused by `rubygems-bundler` also needing an update (to 1.4.4), see https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4180