# Git has not staged and modified files after switching branch

Tags: git, merge, version-control, branch, git-checkout

Currently I'm struggeling with the problem, that git *produces* unstaged files after switching a branch with using `git checkout f_refact_reg`.

My tree is currently looking like this:

```
-------------------------master
        |------------------dev
            |---f_refact_reg
```

What I've done:

1. I added and commited all changes in the `dev` branch and pushed it to the remote repository
2. Checked out the `master` branch and merged `dev`
3. *Making a release*
4. Pushing to the remote branch
5. Checking out the `f_refact_reg` branch
6. Tried to merge `dev` into `f_refact_reg` to be up to date. Than this appears:

[image: Git issue]

I've already tried to override those changes or stash them and then remove the stashed files, or just checking the files out. But nothing seems to help.

How does I can solve this issue and why are this files "changed" after simply checking out the branch?

Thank you all!

Comment: @poke I try what you marked, but this does not explain why this happens after checking out a branch...

Comment: From what you show in the screenshot, it explains it perfectly: You have modified files, you use `git checkout -- .` to replace those files and you still have modified files. That’s exactly what’s covered in the linked question.

Comment: I've not changed them. This happens after `git checkout f_refact_reg`.

Comment: That’s my point: you did not change them. There appear to be no changes, but Git still thinks there are changes in those files. Please check that linked question.

Comment: @BendEg: what poke is saying is : you may see the effects of git automatically changing the line endings of these two files to suit your platform. Check the diff (in winmerge or something) for these files to see if they differ only on line endings. See [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016404/git-status-shows-modifications-git-checkout-file-doesnt-remove-them) for more details on this problem.