# Git error: Encountered 7 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't

Tags: git, git-lfs

How to clean repo, if staged files marked as modified?

After

```
git reset --hard
```

I get

```
Encountered 7 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't:
```

Running `git clean -fdx` (which deletes everything, including untracked directories and anything in `.gitignore`) doesn't help, either.

Comment: That error message sounds like something you would get from `git-lfs`. I don't actually use git-lfs so I'm not sure about this (nor what to do about it), but if so, maybe the git-lfs tag would be good.

Comment: yes, lfs is used

Comment: @KateZz did you ever find an answer to this?  We use git-lfs as well and I just checked out a branch and got that that error.

Comment: It's easy to run into this situation if you add `filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs` entries to your `.gitattributes` that match already commited files. If you want to make sure, they are converted at the same time, use `git rm --cached .` and `git add -A` to switch them to LFS pointers. (Of course assuming you are on an otherwise clean working directory.)
If you forget to convert them, the problem may show up much later. I am not sure when exactly - probably when they get touched somehow.

Comment: Doing a `git lfs pull` in the repo before committing resolved this issue for me

Comment: I agree that the "pointers" error implicates LFS. I didn't say so because I didn't want to bias first responses. I know very little about LFS. I asked my engineering contact whether the repo uses it, but his answer was vague; I don't think he knows much more about it than I do.

@CPayne, I ran `git lfs pull`, but it didn't help

@Tilman Vogel, your comment seems to be directed to the person who enabled LFS for the repo, which isn't me. Is there anything I can do? Should I try to find out who enabled LFS and get them to help?

Answer (score 460):

Like **Travis Heeter** mentioned in his answer, Try the following command sequence:

```
git lfs uninstall
git reset --hard
git lfs install
git lfs pull
```

In case if this is not working (because this was not working for me), the following hack may work:

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
git rm .gitattributes
git reset .
git checkout .
```

This worked for me!

Comment: After battling with this across different branches and doing things like making temp branches and committing the problem file to those instead, I still found I had one branch left with a Unity asset file stuck behind. This method worked brilliantly.

Comment: I needed to do a merge with another branch, but could not get rid of those non-pointer files. Driving me crazy... So, I did a `git lfs uninstall`, `git reset hard <commit>`, `git merge <branch>`, `git lfs install` and `git lfs pull`. Finally :). Thanks.

Comment: Ops, my previous comment should have said `git reset --hard`... No way to edit in Stackoverflow after a while, sigh...

Comment: This worked for me but I had to add some sleeps in between the commands so that it could work as a bash script, see my code below.

Comment: Worked for me BUT on windows, had to use `PowerShell` rather than `git bash`

Comment: what is the difference between git reset . and git reset --hard above?

is "git reset ." just a reset with a default of mixed instead of the hard reset above?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `git reset --hard`, the 2nd step on either path, fails with the same message as the questioner so I can't get past that step

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the second set of commands. `git rm --cached -r .` is redundant with `git reset --hard`. `git rm .gitattributes` deletes and stages `.gitattributes` then `git reset .` unstages it, then `git checkout .` restores the `.gitattributes`; so it appears to do nothing. It all seems like a long way to write `git reset --hard`. What am I missing?

Comment: For me, the second set of commands just conceals the problem. It comes back immediately when invoking "rm .git/index && git reset --hard" (be careful to backup local changes first!). It will come back step-by-step once Git is forced to perform a content check (e.g. because timestamps of the problematic files have changed). IMHO, this problem is an inconsistency in the repository itself and needs to be fixed by an appropriate commit.

Comment: The second one works for me.

Comment: Finally! The second one worked for me on windows.

Comment: The second one works for me.

Comment: I found neither the first or second one worked for me, but combining them both along with a "git status" worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77701176

Answer (score 163):

I had this exact error with some files stored with git-LFS and [solved it the same way I've solved a linending induced borked index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016404/git-status-shows-modifications-git-checkout-file-doesnt-remove-them/18792689#18792689) .

Clear the cache and do a hard reset:

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

This was *significantly* faster than a fresh clone for me due to the huge git-LFS files in my repo.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but the second code block of [AnsarAdimu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804224) did. Didn't try the first code block of their answer because uninstalling git lfs seemed a bit much.

Comment: This worked for me. I think the error was originally caused by files being checked in by a user NOT using Git LFS, then pulled down to a user who DID have Git LFS, which then didn't know how to deal with it. So those non-Git-LFS-managed files need to be removed from the repository.

Comment: This didn't work for me, either.

Comment: This worked for me.  My issue was I changed the .gitattributes file on a feature branch to include all the files that should have been in git LFS and then when I merged to main it caused this issue.

Comment: Is `git rm --cached -r .` is redundant with `git reset --hard`?

Answer (score 134):

Since git lfs 2.5.0, there is a new command available that makes this easier ([docs](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-migrate.adoc#import-without-rewriting-history)):

```
git lfs migrate import --no-rewrite "broken file.jpg" "another broken file.png" ...
```

This "migrates" files to git lfs which should be in lfs as per `.gitattributes`, but aren't at the moment (which is the reason for your error message).

`--no-rewrite` prevents git from applying this to older commits, it creates a single new commit instead.

Use `-m "commitmessage"` to set a commitmessage for that commit.

Comment: This solution worked for me. 

I originally found it from this blog post:
https://tech-notes.maxmasnick.com/fixing-files-that-should-have-been-pointers-in-lfs-but-werent

Comment: Does `no-rewrite` mean there will still possibly be multiple binary versions in your git history instead of just pointers?

Comment: yes. old commits won't be changed, so whatever is contained in there stays in the repo. if you want to wipe the file from all commits, you'll need to rewrite the history (omitting `--no-rewrite` would do that I assume)

Comment: This should be the top-ranked answer.  Works!

Comment: Agree with @BrianCraig.  Should be top answer as of **2021**

Comment: This solved my issue.

Comment: I found I also had to do a `git lfs pull` after running this command

Comment: Unfortunately this left me with a commit that changed the status of my files, which I really don't want to push to the server.  I had to revert the local commit and now I'm still left with those problem files.

Answer (score 78):

The problem comes from the mismatch beetween the filetypes marked as to be tracked by git LFS in the `.gitattributes` and some matching files already under conventional non-LFS version control.

So the simplest workaround here is to just remove the `.gitattributes` file for a moment:

```
git rm .gitattributes
git reset .
git checkout .
```

Afterwards you can checkout any other branch.

One more advice: When adding a new filetype to git LFS, prefer not to do this by hand by modifying the `.gitattributes` but e.g. by running:

```
git lfs track PATTERN
```

where PATTERN is the pattern for matching files, e.g `*.so`

This way all already non-LFS versioned files matching the new tracking-pattern will be marked dirty and can be simlpy added, i.e. converted to git LFS (file pointers).

Comment: I can confirm this almost always works with Git 2.18.0, 2.26.2 and 2.27.0. If it doesn't work in first try, delete the offending files and run above commands again.

Comment: "*just remove the .gitattributes file for a moment*" Could you explain how those three command do that? It seems to delete `.gitattributes` and stage the delete, then undo the stage, then undo the delete. The net result seems to be nothing. Is there some `git-lfs` magic?

Comment: Finally, this approach worked for me...

Comment: Had to do a slight variant of @keremispirli 's suggestion. Delete the file, execute the first two commands in this answer, then do a git pull, then run the final command. This seems to have cleared things up everywhere.

Answer (score 31):

This can happen when you do a checkout that contains files which should have been been tracked by LFS as specified in `.gitattributes` but somehow they've been committed directly instead. Most likely you have another program managing your repository such as a git GUI or IDE.

This can be frustrating because these files appear out of nowhere and prevent you from making checkouts. As soon as you stash your changes they return! If you get stuck in this situation, a quick fix is to commit these changes on a temporary branch so that you can checkout again.

To genuinely fix this problem, make sure you've committed the files as LFS pointers. This should be as simple as using `git add`. Check your work using `git lfs status` before committing. `git lfs ls-files` will show what files LFS is managing.

`git lfs status` is misleading since it reads `Git LFS objects to be committed` when it really lists all changes. Files that you expect to be tracked by LFS should read something like `(LFS: c9e4f4a)` or `(Git: c9e4f4a -> LFS: c9e4f4a)` and not `(Git: c9e4f4a)`.

By way of example, I found this to be a problem when adding image assets through Xcode 9.2 where I added "CalendarChecked.png" which it automatically added:

```
$ git status
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   Example/Assets.xcassets/CalendarChecked.imageset/CalendarChecked.png

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Example/Assets.xcassets/CalendarChecked.imageset/CalendarChecked.png

$ git lfs status

Git LFS objects to be committed:

    Example/Assets.xcassets/CalendarChecked.imageset/CalendarChecked.png (Git: c9e4f4a)

Git LFS objects not staged for commit:

    Example/Assets.xcassets/CalendarChecked.imageset/CalendarChecked.png (File: c9e4f4a)

$ git add Example/Assets.xcassets/CalendarChecked.imageset/CalendarChecked.png`
$ git lfs status

Git LFS objects to be committed:

    Empty/Empty/Assets.xcassets/CalendarChecked.imageset/CalendarChecked.png (LFS: c9e4f4a)

Git LFS objects not staged for commit:

$
```

Answer (score 30):

Neither of these solutions worked for me, but I pieced together a few sources to finally get all this fixed.

1. ***Push any changes you don't want to lose***

   If you can... If not, or if you don't care about your changes, press on.
2. ***Stop Everything***

   SourceTree, any servers, file explorers and browsers. Sometimes this stuff won't work if it's being used somewhere else. When in doubt, stop it - with this it's better to overkill.

   Also, go into Task Manager, force quit any `bash.exe` processes. Git Bash tends to hold files open after you close the window.
3. ***Open a Command Window (or Terminal)***

   `cd` to your local repo.
4. ***Uninstall `lfs`***

   `> git lfs uninstall`

   Then it'll say something like:

   ```
   Hooks for this repository have been removed.
   Global Git LFS configuration has been removed.
   ```
5. ***Reset***

   `> git reset --hard`

   It'll go through a lot of output probably...
6. ***Reinstall `lfs`***

   `> git lfs install`

   This may again say it found files that should have been pointers but weren't. *That's OK, keep going!*
7. ***Pull with `lfs`***

   `> git lfs pull`

   Hopefully pulling with lfs will overwrite the files that got borked.

   A few of my sources said at this point their repo was working again, but not me personally. You can open SourceTree or whatever to check if you want, but you may have to start from the top if it didn't work.
8. ***Migrate***

   The core issue here is that `lfs`, instead of downloading large files like audio, video, images - anything larger than 1Mb - it just points to them on a server. This is useful if you have a bunch of large files, you're not pulling down all that stuff. So your local repo is smaller and nimbler. However, through circumstances I'm not sure about, it seems possible to corrupt the pointers. I'm sure this is an issue that the lfs people are aware of and are working on, but for now we have to work it out ourselves.

   **What we've done so far is**

   - uninstall `lfs`
   - delete everything
   - reinstall `lfs`
   - pull everything

   So now we have all these *things* in our folder that are either **files** or **pointers to files**, and `lfs` needs to figure out if any files should be pointers and vise versa. And hopefully by performing the steps above we deleted the corrupted pointers. So we're going to perform `migrate` to kick off the procedure that goes through the files on the repo, and if they're greater than 1Mb, lfs is going to replace them with a pointer.

   `> git lfs migrate`
9. ***More Errors***

   Here's a point at which others have stopped and said they were working again, but not me. I got an error:

   > Error in git rev-list... exit status 128 fatal: bad revision '...`v1.0.0`'

   @guneyozsan over at a [github help page](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2450#issuecomment-454794321), posted this final piece to the puzzle, even though it didn't fix his issue.

   `> git lfs migrate info --include-ref=v1.0.0`

   Notice the version matches the version that errored - `v1.0.0`. You will need to replace `v1.0.0` with whatever version you got in your error.

   I haven't found a source on why this error occurs but my guess is that the lfs version number generated by `migrate` on your local repo doesn't match the source version. For me, all this started when SourceTree crashed during a push and I forced a machine reboot, and when that happens, lfs doesn't know how to deal with it, so it just gets stuck in this loop where it's trying to update, but it can't read the corrupted data. Hence the lengthy troubleshooting.
10. ***Stash and Pull***

When you open SourceTree, you'll probably see that it wants to add all your files back. Don't do that. ***Stash, then pull***.

And boom, the horror is hopefully over. If not, this [git hub page](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2450#issuecomment-454794321) or [this one](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1939) may help you more, but this is what worked for me.

Comment: `git lfs migrate` was a life saver. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Ensure you have `git lfs` version 2.5 or higher installed ([download here](https://git-lfs.github.com/)).

Check you are using the `git lfs` version you downloaded (2.7.2 for me):

```
>git lfs version
git-lfs/2.7.2
```

Run:

`git lfs migrate import --fixup --everything`

Pull your branch and fix any merge conflicts.

Found in this [github comment](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1939#issuecomment-425308341).

Comment: This is the correct answer, everything else failed for me.

Answer (score 20):

run

```
git add --renormalize .
```

and commit those  changes. It is safe to do even when another user is doing the same on another branch, since the LFS pointer is derived from the hash of the file. It might also catch some files with wrong line endings.

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted, it's exactly the correct command to use and it worked for me (just instead of `.` pass the path to files that need fixing to speed up the process).

Comment: Should be chosen answer.  Much less destructive than other approaches.

Comment: This approach worked for me to fix files that were both LFS tracked and checked in as the original files. After doing this simple command for each file mentioned by `git lfs fsck --pointers` and then doing `git commit` then problem was fixed.

Answer (score 7):

One possible cause for this error is **due to git LFS-related changes to `.gitattributes` that impacts already added files in a repo.**

(I'm not sure of the exact steps to reproduce, but the issue seemed to occur when I touched a file that was newly affected by the .gitattributes that was previously committed as a non-LFS file that should now be an LFS file. The issue seemed aggravated by switching branches, or at least made it impossible to switch branches until the issue was resolved.)

In this case, I used the steps below **to prevent this error from occurring repeatedly**.

---

1. Fix the issue for the branch you are on by following one of the other answers here (e.g. to clear the cache and reset. I found [BheeMa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804224/5170571) to be effective.)
2. Go to your main branch, and ensure there is nothing to commit with `git status`
3. **Force git to recheck and "reapply" git attributes changes**

From [Ratata Tata's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52110101/5170571) in [How to make change to .gitattributes take effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48642692/5170571))

```
 git rm --cached -r .
 git add -A
```

*Warning: make sure in step 2 that there was nothing to commit, as the steps above will add any files that were not previously versioned*

4. Verify the results with `git status` (it should only have modified relevant files to become LFS pointers, i.e. files that can potentially cause the "encountered files that should have been pointers" error) and commit changes
5. (Optionally, merge/rebase this fix to all other branches if possible. Otherwise, this error could pop up again when switching to those branches. Note that it may be necessary to repeat the initial fix for each branch as per step 1 to be safe, though it could be ok just to commit the affected files.)

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer worked for me but it would only work when I manually typed the commands, I put sleeps between each command and now it works as a bash script:

```
git rm --cached -r .
sleep 1
git reset --hard
sleep 1
git rm .gitattributes
sleep 1
git reset .
sleep 1
git checkout .
```

Answer (score 5):

This just shows one more time what a pile of dog**** GIT-LFS is.

You can get into this situation if:

1. The file is contained in `common-base-branch` and not in LFS
2. In a branch `lfs-branch` based on `common-base-branch`, the file was moved to LFS
3. In another branch `non-lfs-branch` also based on `common-base-branch`, the file was modified.

Or alternatively:

1. The file is NOT contained in `common-base-branch`
2. In a branch `lfs-branch` based on `common-base-branch`, the file was added to LFS
3. In another branch `non-lfs-branch` also based on `common-base-branch`, the file was added (but not to LFS.

In both cases, when you try to merge `non-lfs-branch` into `lfs-branch`, you get this kind of error.

You may ask why this should even happen in the first place, but the answer is that a lot of software is developed by more than once person (which is why you have version control systems like GIT in the first place), and people don't always talk to each other, or LFS is introduced later in the history of a project in a feature branch, while "normal" development still goes on in other branches.

**This is a legitimate merge conflict situation, not a bug or corrupted working directory or anything (as some of the other answers suggest).** GIT-LFS just handles it poorly.

What you want to do now is to make sure the right version of the conflicted files goes into GIT-LFS, so you may want to choose an answer to this question which does just that... (TODO: Insert link to at least one answer that works)

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to get away from that bad commit, you can go back to master by

```
git reset --soft origin/master
git reset --hard
```

Then you are free from the nasty 7 non-LFS files:-)

Answer (score 4):

Same as @John Kugelman above, but I put it in a alias because I had to do it a bunch of times.

```
    
git rm --cached -r . > /dev/null && git reset --hard > /dev/null && git rm .gitattributes > /dev/null && git reset . && git checkout . > /dev/null
```

Comment: This man is my hero of the day. ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

The following process will add a commit which replaces all binary files that should be lfs pointers with lfs pointers.

1. Clean working copy completely. Together with the force add below this prevents any files getting added or removed due to .gitignore patterns.

   ```
   git clean -dfx
   git reset --hard
   git checkout -- .
   ```
2. Add remove for everything to staging area. Working copy will not be touched.

   ```
   git rm --cached -r .
   ```
3. Readd all files from working copy again. This will basically undo the previous command but will reevaluate lfs filters. Use -f to ignore .gitignore. All files present were previously checked in and should get added again.

   ```
   git add -f .
   ```
4. You staging area now should only contain the binary files that previously raised the 'should have been pointers' error.

   ```
   git commit -m "moved files to lfs"
   ```

Comment: I managed to make this work, but for me, I had to make a git commit between the `git rm` and the `git add`, otherwise `gitk` would indicate that I had just re-added the files as binaries and not LFS pointers. Maybe gitk was confused, but to avoid any risks, the two-commit solution seemed more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem I ran into:

Say you created a branch, and you somehow committed files as non-LFS. So then you tried to correct it by later committing the LFS version of the files on the same branch. However, now you can't rebase or squash because you'll keep running into this "files that should have been pointers but weren't" error in the middle of the rebase.

Solve using `git reset --soft`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/2516916

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was one file under lfs rules (I'm assuming it was checked in without lfs installed or something).

So I found it's extension in the .gitattributes file and commented this line out like

```
#*.7z filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

saved this .gitattributes then `git status` showed no problems.

After that I've uncommented this line (removed #), saved .gitattributes and `git status` still shows no problems.

Answer (score 2):

What helped me, without touching the whole repo, was the `git restore` command which was added in git 2.23

`git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree -- affected_files`

Execute this command *a few times* until all of the warnings are gone.

Answer (score 1):

none of the above commands worked for me, I found an answer [here](https://qiita.com/kazuki-ma/items/782cd1cd7eca2fe988b7)

```
git status -s | cut -c 4- | xargs git update-index --assume-unchanged
rm .git/index && git reset
```

Comment: Thank you!  None of the other answers worked for me either except this.

Comment: Why this may or may not work, you may want to explain what this does (the link goes to a website in Japanese). Whether or not this is the right solution may depend on the cause of the problem.

Comment: @FlorianWinter the cause of the problem is described in the question above, another reason that this error happens is some people in the team have not enabled git-lfs,so this command have just updated the index , and when you have many files to fix, we used this command: `git status -s | cut -c 4- |` to collect all the files, I just wrote the answer that worked for me in purpose to help the people who faced the same troubles as me

Answer (score 1):

## Analysis

That's because the files are not tracked by LFS, but they matches some .gitattributes files' description.

For example,

server/.gitattributes:

```
conf/** filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

- server/conf/client.conf is too large and is tracked by LFS
- server/conf/client.gflags is tracked in git instead of LFS

However, client.gflags matches the server/.gitattributes description, and git will pull it from LFS, but it doesn't have the LFS info, and the error will be thrown up.

## Solution

Find the .gitattributes file whose description hit the `Encoutered file`, delete the wrong description or optimize some wildcard character match.

Optimize the example above,
server/.gitattributes:

```
conf/client.conf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [karyon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57820265/3759732) answer, after performing **migrate** to fix the local state:

```
git lfs migrate import --no-rewrite "broken file.jpg" "another broken file.png" ...
```

You have and extra commit which you probably want to get rid of.

Considering **.gitattributes** is already fixed on you main / master branch, one can just rebase the local branch onto the one containing the fix, usually:

```
git rebase upstream/master
```

And this extra commit will be dropped automatically, since it is meaningless at this point.

Answer (score 0):

When it is obviously an error that shows up out of nowhere, this is what we do in our team:

1. Disable lfs for that specific type file (modifying .gitattributes or via SourceTree menus)
2. The change will dissapear and you will see a change on .gitattributes instead
3. Remove the problem:

   3.1 One solution is to execute git reset --hard. Another way, discard changes. Sometimes the file will not come up again.

   3.2.1 If the previous solution doesn't work, repeat 1 and 2. Then make sure that this branch you are in (A) has already commited and pushed everything except those annoying files.  Then commit your change, but not push.

   3.2.2: Go to another branch (B)

   3.2.3: Remove that local branch (A) where you performed the commit to .gitattributes, forcing the removal even when it says there's a commit that hasn't been pushed. It will forget that commit (it can afterwards be removed via GC or whatever but it's not a big deal if the file that has the error is not huge)

   3.2.4: Checkout the branch A again. It will download the previous status of the repository without the annoying files and LFS settings set up the correct way.

That always works!

Answer (score 0):

Loads of answer on this with multiple steps to fix.

If you are just in a broken state, like stuck on a branch because you can't reset/discard the changes to the problem file(s): deleting the `.gitattributes` file maybe enough to allow you to make your next git move. Once you have made your git move you may then have to restoring the `.gitattributes` file but at least you are unstuck.

I wished I had known this before trying all the above. It is a low risk option to try at least.

Answer (score 0):

Here with this embellishment that doesn't require reinstalling the lfs hooks or obscuring any `.gitattributes` files:

```
git -c filter.lfs.smudge= -c filter.lfs.clean= reset --hard
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off [Pellet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63680211), I found that sleeps even up to 10s *sometimes* weren't working. Instead, a single call to `git status` before `git reset .` always worked without needing any sleeps, probably thanks to some kind of refreshing that happens.

The `git lfs uninstall` and `git lfs install` commands from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804224) were also necessary for me. Combining it all:

```
resetlfs() {
  pushd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)" > /dev/null

  git lfs uninstall

  git rm --cached -r .
  git reset --hard
  git rm .gitattributes

  git lfs install
  git status

  git reset .
  git checkout .

  popd > /dev/null
}
```

Note that **this approach only hides** the .gitattributes violations (useful if you're just trying to switch branches!), whereas **[karyon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57820265/1436259) resolves them permanently**.