# Git LFS alteration: what does this odd sequence of commands really do

Tags: git, git-lfs

could someone explain to me what this series of commands actually do?

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
git rm .gitattributes
git reset .
git checkout .
```

I took it from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804224/1256452) to [Git error: Encountered 7 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704572/git-error-encountered-7-files-that-should-have-been-pointers-but-werent/54221959). It does what it's supposed to do but I would like to know why it works and what it does. It usually feels super scary to blindly follow instructions containing --hard, reset and rm...

Comment: Are you using `git-lfs`?

Comment: Yes, I am... I think that's where my original problem arose.

Comment: What is your original problem?

Comment: [I'm not sure what those commands are supposed to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704572/git-error-encountered-7-files-that-should-have-been-pointers-but-werent/54221959#comment125470189_54804224).

Comment: "my original problem", and what is that original problem? This is probably one of the poster children of an X/Y problem. You have a problem, you have found something that looks like a solution, but you don't understand it, so you ask about the solution, and then you refer to your original problem just as "the original problem". Problem is, we don't know what that original problem is. And yes, you're absolutely 100% correct to be scared of `reset` and `reset --hard`. If you search for questions here on SO where people ask how to restore files lost using git, that command is behind it 9/10 times

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear but the original problem was the one linked in "here" in my question... I thought that was deducible. So my original problem is solved but I wanted to understand what the steps did so I don't have to google similar problems every time. So the poster children just want to learn instead of following some incomprehensible sequence of instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could someone explain to me what this series of commands actually do?

[It seems to be a long winded way of writing `git reset --hard` with most of it effectively doing nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704572/git-error-encountered-7-files-that-should-have-been-pointers-but-werent/54221959#comment125470189_54804224), but I could be wrong. See the end of this answer.

---

I can explain `git reset --hard`.

When a Git checkout is dirty there are two areas to clean up.

- The working tree (ie. the files themselves)
- The staging area (ie. what you've Git added)

For basic Git, without `git-lfs`, you need two commands.

- `git reset --hard` (the default is HEAD, the current commit)
- `git clean`

`git-reset` is kind of like `git-checkout` but on steroids. It changes which commit you have checked out, but you can control whether the staging area and working tree change with it.

`git reset --soft` only changes to the new commit, your files and staged changes are left alone. `git reset --soft HEAD^` will move you to the previous commit but all the changes in the commit will be staged, and all the unstaged changes will remain. This is useful if you want to redo a commit, and I have it aliased to `redo`.

`git reset --mixed` changes the commit and resets the staging area. `git reset --mixed HEAD^` is like above, but all the previous commit's changes will be unstaged.

`git reset --hard` changes the commit and resets both the staging area and your files. This wipes all your changes and puts you back into a clean state. `git reset --hard HEAD` wipes out all your changes and restores you to the current commit. `git reset --hard HEAD^` wipes out all your changes and restores you to the previous commit; this is useful if you want to undo a commit, and I have it aliased to `undo`.

Last commit you had checked out is always `ORIG_HEAD` so you can always return to that with `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`.

Finally, if you have any untracked files [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) will delete them.

See [Reset Demystified](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified) for more.

---

> What is that answer doing?

- git rm --cached -r .

This clears the staging area. It is not necessary because...

- git reset --hard

...this also clears the staging area and moves you to a pristine version of your current commit, as discussed above.

- git rm .gitattributes

[gitattributes](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) let you define attributes on paths in your repository. Tools such as `git-lfs` use it to mark which files are using LFS. Blowing the whole thing away will reset *all* attributes, so depending on what other tools you're using this might not be a good idea.

- git reset .

This is `git reset --mixed HEAD`. This would unstage the `git rm` they just did. I don't know why you'd want that.

- git checkout .

This is `git checkout HEAD` which restores `.gitattributes` making the whole exercise moot.

So, unless I'm missing something, all that is just `git reset --hard HEAD`.

Comment: To be blunt, some of the commands from that linked answer seems to be just "throw random sh** at the wall and see what sticks" type of problem solving. Good that it worked, but I doubt all of it was necessary.

Comment: I updated the question itself, and yes, it's definitely a thing to bypass LFS.