# git status say nothing to commit, but can't switch branch

Tags: git, branch, git-commit, git-checkout

I'm working on windows, Thanks for git professionals for any help on this.

```
PS G:\Solid\WebPortals> git status

On branch pos-event-waiver
nothing to commit, working tree clean
PS G:\Solid\WebPortals> git checkout pos-exchange-bill
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        Site/WebPortals/assets/typescript/pos/cart/waiver.component.ts
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

[image]

Comment: Is that .ts file ignored on one or both of those two branches?

Comment: Thanks for replying, i already fixed this problem as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016404/git-status-shows-modifications-git-checkout-file-doesnt-remove-them/2016426)

Comment: I'm sorry but each question must stand on its own, you can't expect people to go hunt through your other questions to see if there's more context.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your local branch pos-event-waiver is not set to track the remote branch. To fix this and track master branch, do:

`git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master`

Try `git status` now to get the status of your current branch, and you can commit or stash your changes, as required.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i already fixed this problem as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016404/git-status-shows-modifications-git-checkout-file-doesnt-remove-them/2016426)