# Git fails to checkout PDF file from index

Tags: git

I'd like to revert a file to the version of the last commit, but it is still displayed as modified after the checkout.

This is the situation before:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   doc/slides/slides.pdf
...
```

Then I want to revert it:

```
$ git checkout doc/slides/slides.pdf
Updated 1 path from the index
```

Afterwards it is still displayed as modified:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   doc/slides/slides.pdf
...
```

I even tried to remove it and use Git to check it out again, but it's still displayed as modified. `git diff` says:

```
Binary files a/doc/slides/slides.pdf and b/doc/slides/slides.pdf differ
```

I'm using pre-commit (with hooks) and DVC. But I doubt this shouldn't make a difference here.

Comment: Have you tried `use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git status shows modifications, git checkout -- <file> doesn't remove them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016404/git-status-shows-modifications-git-checkout-file-doesnt-remove-them)

Comment: @mkrieger1 no, to all questions :( It's Linux, so case sensitive, git restore doesn't change anything and it's a binary file so line endings also won't matter.

Comment: Note that you can still set Git up to modify a file during extraction from index to work-tree, even on Linux. It's not exactly *normal* to do that, though. If you didn't do that, it shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was really stupid. Nothing to do with Git.

I still had pdflatex running in the background with a file watcher without noticing it. So the PDF got recreated every time I reverted it.