# Updating and committing only a file's permissions using git version control

Tags: git

Just turned an `some.sh` file into an executable (`chmod 755 ...`), the permissions were updated but not the content. Is there a way to *commit* the file into git, so that the executable bit will be restored/set on *clone* / *checkout* / *pull* ?

**Update:** how can I track that the new permissions were submitted to `github`?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

By default, git will update execute file permissions if you change them. It will not change or track any other permissions.

If you don't see any changes when modifying execute permission, you probably have a configuration in git which ignore file mode.

Look into your project, in the `.git` folder for the `config` file and you should see something like this:

```
[core]
    filemode = false
```

You can either change it to `true` in your favorite text editor, or run:

```
git config core.filemode true
```

Then, you should be able to commit normally your files. It will only commit the permission changes.

Comment: thank you! how can I track that the permission changes were submitted to `github`?

Comment: You can see it when you view a file (for example, on [Rails gitignore file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/.gitignore), you will find 100644 as the file permission)

Comment: Making permissions changes on Windows with git (actually changing the file permissions and committing): http://blog.lesc.se/2011/11/how-to-change-file-premissions-in-git.html

Comment: This answer is wrong! Git only tracks if a file is executable or not. It does not track other file permission like writable or readable. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/11231682/2311074 for more.

Comment: For me webstorm did not catch the change , but in `git status`, I see changes..

Comment: Is there a way to do this globally? `git config --global` didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 361):

@fooMonster article worked for me

```
# git ls-tree HEAD
100644 blob 55c0287d4ef21f15b97eb1f107451b88b479bffe    script.sh
```

As you can see the file has 644 permission (ignoring the 100). We would like to change it to 755:

```
# git update-index --chmod=+x script.sh
```

commit the changes

```
# git commit -m "Changing file permissions"
[master 77b171e] Changing file permissions
0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
mode change 100644 => 100755 script.sh
```

Comment: It should be noted that you actually have to use '-x/+x'. You can not set any other permissions or a bitmask.

Comment: note using `git commit -a` didn't do anything for me, however setting message on the command line did.  Bit of a quirk

Comment: The command order should be : 
`# git update-index --chmod=+x script.sh`
`# git ls-tree HEAD`
`# git commit -m "Changing file permissions"`
`# git push`

Answer (score 1):

Simply run `git update-index`

Then you will see your changes in `git status` and can commit them.

Answer (score 0):

As Adam wrote: Git does not track the file mode in its entirety.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corefileMode