# File permission issues when developing with Windows / hosting with Unix

Tags: linux, windows, git, chmod

I am developing a website on my windows laptop, and I use Git for the version control.

When I add my files to Git, they are added under the mode **644**. The problem is, on my Linux server, I need the files to be **775**. So what I do is, every time I deploy, I have to run `chmod 775 -R .` on my linux server and then commit the mode changes.

This is really anoying, time consuming, and result in lot of stranges commits.

My question is, how can I make my IDE (PHPStorm) create the files direcly with mode **775**? I know Windows does not use the same file permission system as UNIX, but there must be a way to set the files permissions on windows that translates to 775 in Linux?

I tried to use "chmod" command on windows using Cygwin or similar tools, with no luck, Git always saves the files as **644** when I commit on windows.

Comment: In theory you could create either a *pre-commit* hook which uses `git update-index --chmod` as jas_raj suggested. Alternativly you could use a post-recieve hook on the serverside to update your file permissions as you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

See: [Updating file permissions only in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516201/updating-file-permissions-only-in-git)

In summary, `git update-index --chmod` should do what you need.

Comment: Well, I want 775, not 755, so I don't think that's helping me that much? And I tried it, after this command, git still commit my windows files as 644...

Comment: --chmod will only change the user execute permission, it doesn't look like it supports changing group or other. However it will ensure the file keeps the user execute permission - I tested committing a file on Windows, update the permission and then checking out on Linux. Seems to work here.

Comment: You updating the permission on windows using what tool?