# How to change a file status on git remote repository?

Tags: git

I created a shellscript file and pushed on a git remote repository.
The shellscript file is not executable by givern permission, so I changed file permission on a local and pushed it on the remote repository.
The problem is, the changed permission for the file is not applied at all, but to the file on the local repository, YES.

My question is "How to change a file status on git remote repository?"

Cheers

Comment: Have a look at this thread:
[Updating file permissions in git][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516201/updating-file-permissions-only-in-git

Comment: thanks for asnwering me. I've already looked at that article but that one seems to work before committing takes place. The situation im facing is when committing has done already.